# How to uninstall Python 2.7 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4?

Tags: python, macos, uninstallation, python-2.7

I want to completely remove Python 2.7 from my Mac OS X 10.6.4. I managed to remove the entry from the `PATH` variable by reverting my `.bash_profile`. But I also want to remove all directories, files, symlinks, and entries that got installed by the Python 2.7 install package. I've got the install package from http://www.python.org/. What directories/files/configuration file entries do I need to remove? Is there a list somewhere?

Answer (score 950, accepted):

#### Do not attempt to remove any Apple-supplied system Python which are in `/System/Library` and `/usr/bin`, as this may break your whole operating system.

---

**NOTE:** *The steps listed below do **not** affect the Apple-supplied Python 2.7; they only remove a third-party Python framework, like those installed by [python.org installers](https://www.python.org/downloads/).*

---

The complete list is [documented here](http://bugs.python.org/issue7107).  Basically, all you need to do is the following:

1. Remove the third-party Python 2.7 framework

   ```
    sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
   ```
2. Remove the Python 2.7 applications directory

   ```
    sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Python 2.7"
   ```
3. Remove the symbolic links, in `/usr/local/bin`, that point to this Python version. See them using

   ```
    ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7'
   ```

and then run the following command to remove all the links:

```
    cd /usr/local/bin/
    ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7' | awk '{print $9}' | tr -d @ | xargs rm
```

4. If necessary, edit your shell profile file(s) to remove adding `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7` to your `PATH` environment file.  Depending on which shell you use, any of the following files may have been modified:
   `~/.bash_login`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.cshrc`, `~/.profile`, `~/.tcshrc`, `~/.zshrc`, and/or `~/.zprofile`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Ned, I did remove it, and found out the hard way that you have to reinstall Mac OS X. I'm leaving this here for anyone else who comes along and thinks the same thing I did. Don't remove Python in /System/Library/Frameworks/... None of your apps will work and you'll have to reinstall OS X.

Comment: Python 2.7 is the default system Python on recent systems, while on 10.6.4 it was 2.6 and 2.7 was user-installed. DO NOT UNINSTALL 2.7 FROM A RECENT OS X SYSTEM.

Comment: The steps above do not remove the system Python from *any* version of OS X.  System Pythons are installed in `/System/Library/Frameworks` (which you should never modify), not `/Library/Frameworks`.

Comment: a coworker of mine screwed up their python installation and had to also clear out `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` in addition to the above.

Comment: `brew doctor` can also be used to find the unused symlinks.

Comment: @NedDeily in the last line of Step 3 I received approximately 20 messages along the lines of `rm: 2to3-2: Permission denied` `rm: 2to3-2.7: Permission denied` `rm: easy_install: Permission denied`. Does this matter? is there a way to get around it? (maybe add `sudo` somewhere?)

Comment: As alternative for step 3, this should be a safer command that avoids choking on unexpected filenames in the directory: `sudo find /usr/local/bin -maxdepth 1 -lname "*/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/*" -delete`

Comment: @user5783745, you can add a `sudo` before `rm`.

Comment: Need to know if `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` should be left behind or not.  Or if `/usr/bin/python2.7` is good enough?

Comment: @EgbertS, Step 3 above should remove `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` if it points to the python.org installed 2.7.  The `/usr/local/` hierarchy is reserved for third-party files, not Apple-supplied macOS files.  `/usr/bin/python2.7` is part of the Apple-supplied system Python and should not be altered.

Comment: Thank you, thank you @Martijn Pieters. I almost trashed my Mac. I was trying to install cx_Oracle and it defaulted to python2.7, but I'm working with Python 3.7. There is no need to uninstall Python 2.7. Just install Python3.x and use: `python3 -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade` instead of `python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade` (notice the 3 indicates installation for Python 3.x).

Comment: If you followed these commands and the system stoped working properly, you may not need to reinstall the OS, instead reset your user profile, create a new admin account on the MAC. login with the new account and then rename your old profile name under /users. Now restart your computer and login to your old user again and you should get new settings.

Comment: Substitute the version of Python you want to install... e.g. instead of 2.7 use 3.8

Comment: Wow! Be very careful uninstalling python required for the Mac OS. Thanks for this bold warning. Your comment saved me!

Comment: If you just don't want Terminal to default to Python 2.7, use pyenv: `pyenv install 3.8.2 && pyenv global 3.8.2 && echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: What should i do if after all this steps python 2.7 still didn't deleted?

Comment: Ok.. i've found this answer AFTER i've tried to remove the /System and /usr/bin python and got `Operation not permitted`. Thank god mac saved me from my stupidity

Comment: After all these steps: `<me> % Python --version
Python 2.7.16`

Comment: It should be made clearer not to follow these steps above, now I have to reinstall my entire macOS.

Comment: UPDATE EVERYONE: MacOS Monterary 12.3 comes without the system provided Python 2.7. Gave me a headache thinking that I accidentally uninstalled it somehow and my system was trashed.

Answer (score 79):

This one works:

```sh
cd /usr/local/bin/
ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7' | awk '{print $9}' | tr -d @ | xargs rm
```

Description:
It list all the links, removes `@` character and then removes them.

Comment: I tried every answer provided here, and this is the one that finally did the trick.

Answer (score 63):

Create the symlink to latest version

```
 ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Close and open a new terminal

and try

```
 python --version
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and the same way goes for pip " ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip " then " pip --version" also if you want to upgrade pip use this command "pip install --upgrade pip"

Comment: or try `/usr/bin/` instead of `/usr/local/bin/` depending on your OSX

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working on macOS Monterey as well.

Comment: It requires Super User privilege so you need command "sudo" for that

Answer (score 32):

Trying to uninstall Python with

```
brew uninstall python
```

will **not** remove the natively installed Python but rather the version installed with `brew`.

Comment: I had to do this multiple times to get rid of all the random versions I had

Comment: You can also uninstall a specific version with `brew uninstall python@3.8`

Answer (score 31):

If you installed it using the PKG installer, you can do:

```
pkgutil --pkgs
```

or better:

```
pkgutil --pkgs | grep org.python.Python
```

which will output something like:

```
org.python.Python.PythonApplications-2.7
org.python.Python.PythonDocumentation-2.7
org.python.Python.PythonFramework-2.7
org.python.Python.PythonProfileChanges-2.7
org.python.Python.PythonUnixTools-2.7
```

you can now select which packages you will unlink (remove).

This is the unlink documentation:

```
 --unlink package-id
             Unlinks (removes) each file referenced by package-id. WARNING: This command makes no attempt to perform reference counting or dependency analy-
             sis. It can easily remove files required by your system. It may include unexpected files due to package tainting. Use the --files command first
             to double check.
```

In my example you will type

```
pkgutil --unlink org.python.Python.PythonApplications-2.7
pkgutil --unlink org.python.Python.PythonDocumentation-2.7
pkgutil --unlink org.python.Python.PythonFramework-2.7
pkgutil --unlink org.python.Python.PythonProfileChanges-2.7
pkgutil --unlink org.python.Python.PythonUnixTools-2.7
```

or in one single line:

```
pkgutil --pkgs | grep org.python.Python | xargs -L1 pkgutil -f --unlink
```

Important: --unlink is not available anymore starting with Lion (as of Q1`2014 that would include Lion, Mountain Lion, and Mavericks). If anyone that comes to this instructions try to use it with lion, should try instead to adapt it with what this post is saying: https://wincent.com/wiki/Uninstalling_packages_(.pkg_files)_on_Mac_OS_X

Comment: Unfortunately, depending on `pkgutil` will not remove all files installed by the Python installer because some of them are created during the installation postflight scripts and, as such, are not registered.

Answer (score 14):

No need to uninstall it or going crazy with symbolic links, just use an `alias`. I faced the same problem when upgrading to python 3.7.1.
Just install the new python version using `brew install python` then in your `.bash_profile` create an alias pointing to the new python version; like this: `alias python="/usr/local/bin/python3"` then save and run `source ~/.bash_profile`.
Done.

Answer (score 12):

In regards to deleting the symbolic links, I found this to be useful.

```
find /usr/local/bin -lname '../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/*' -delete
```

Comment: this is a much better idea than parsing the output of `ls` as in the accepted answer

Comment: I keep getting "permission denied" from the above answers. But this one paired with `sudo` did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I faced the same problem when upgrading to python 3.9 from python 2.7.16 Just install the new python version using brew install python or download and install for your OS then

1. ```
   sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
   ```
2. ```
   sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Python 2.7"
   ```
3. ```
   ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7'
   ```
4. then check -> `python --version`
5. in your `.bash_profile` create an alias pointing to the new python version; like this:

   ```
   alias python="/usr/local/bin/python3"
   ```

   then save and run source `~/.bash_profile`.
6. check -> `python --version`

all set now

Answer (score 8):

No need to uninstall old python versions.

Just install new version say python-3.3.2-macosx10.6.dmg
and change the soft link of python to newly installed python3.3

Check the path of default python and python3.3 with following commands

"which python" and "which python3.3"

then delete existing soft link of python and point it to python3.3

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer my question. The question is not whether I need to uninstall an old python versions in order to install a new version.

Comment: This seems the safest approach, since for me, mucking with what the OS puts on the machine doesn't usually turn out so well.  I, too, "got the install package from http://python.org" after encountering syntax issues from python3 statements in a python2 shell.  My first thought was to remove python2 and use python3, instead.  However, from prior posts that confirms the dangers of that action.  This was the better solution for me and follows the idea of "use links to reroute behaviour".  Also, the python3 shell was already installed, just had to type "python3" instead of "python" at the prompt.

Comment: @minhas23 How would I delete the soft link and create a new one?

Answer (score 8):

On a MacOS where `python3` was installed with `brew`:

```
sudo ln -s -f /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
sudo ln -s -f /opt/homebrew/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip
```

Reopen terminal

```
python --version
pip --version
```

Comment: This is the best answer in here. Pretty simple and just works! Thank you.

Comment: I tried removing the other directories as other answers mentioned but nothing was working until I tried this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Onur Güzel provides the solution in his blog post, ["Uninstall Python Package from OS X](http://www.onurguzel.com/uninstall-python-package-from-os-x/).

You should type the following commands into the terminal:

1. `sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`
2. `cd /usr/local/bin`
3. `ls -l . | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework' | awk '{print $9}' | xargs sudo rm`
4. `sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Python x.y"`

   where command x.y is the version of Python installed. According to your question, it should be 2.7.

In Onur's words:

> **WARNING:** This commands will remove all Python versions installed with packages. Python provided from the system will not be affected.

If you have more than 1 Python version installed from python.org, then run the fourth command again, changing "x.y" for each version of Python that is to be uninstalled.

Comment: That solved my issue, I have 2.7.10 and brew installed 2.7.15 and when I ran "python" the 2.7.10 was still showing up not 2.7.15, after your help all is working now, thank you

Comment: This was the solution for my issue. I had a 3.8 installed and could not remember how it was installed. Now nice and clean with python from brew.

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me on Mac OS

1. Download the latest Python 3.x from https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/
2. Install Python 3.x by going through the Installation Steps that show up when you click on the installer
3. `ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /usr/local/bin/python`
4. `ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip`
5. Open a new terminal window and verify `python --version`. Should say 3.x

For step 3, confirm the path for your existing python executable by checking the output of `which python`

Answer (score 4):

**Note**: *If you installed Python using Homebrew, then you can follow the following steps, otherwise look for another solution!*

---

To uninstall Python 2.7.10 which you installed using Homebrew, then you can simply issue the following command:

```
brew uninstall python
```

Similarly, if you want to uninstall Python 3 (which you installed using Homebrew):

```
brew uninstall --force python3
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're thinking about manually removing Apple's default Python 2.7, I'd suggest you hang-fire and do-noting:  Looks like Apple will very shortly do it for you:

### Python 2.7 Deprecated in OSX 10.15 Catalina

Python 2.7- as well as Ruby & Perl- are deprecated in Catalina: (skip to section "***Scripting Language Runtimes***" > "***Deprecations***")

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_catalina_10_15_release_notes

### Apple To Remove Python 2.7 in OSX 10.16

Indeed, if you do nothing at all, according to ***The Mac Observer***, by OSX version 10.16, Python 2.7 will disappear from your system:

https://www.macobserver.com/analysis/macos-catalina-deprecates-unix-scripting-languages/

Given this revelation, I'd suggest the best course of action is do nothing and wait for Apple to wipe it for you.  As Apple is imminently about to remove it for you, doesn't seem worth the risk of tinkering with your Python environment.

**NOTE**: I see the question relates specifically to *OSX v 10.6.4*, but it appears this question has become a pivot-point for all OSX folks interested in removing Python 2.7 from their systems, whatever version they're running.

Comment: 10.14.6  I dont think it still removed,

Comment: it seems that there will be no 10.16, but 11.0 (Big Sur) directly. We are still waiting!

Answer (score 1):

Caution when trying to remove certain python library, Mac OS needs python!
DO NOT remove any Python versions in the following folders:

```
/usr/bin
system/Library
```

These Python  2.7 versions are installed by Apple and used by Mac OS and other software. Deleting Python from these directories can break your system.

Answer (score 0):

Here you will see all the preinstalled versions of python including 2.3, 2.4 and even 2.7.

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions`

But, even with sudo I do not think so, you will be able to remove them. You will get an error - `Operation not permitted`

Answer (score -1):

Install the new python version using
brew install python
In .bash_profile or .zprofile create an alias like this:
alias python="/usr/local/bin/python3"
Done.