# Matplotlib.pyplot on OS X with 64-bit Python from Python.org

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I just installed `numpy` and `matplotlib` on my OS X 10.6.6. I have Python 2.7 from Python.org. When I do an `import matplotlib.pyplot`, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

Is there something I missed? How do I fix this?

**Update 1 (March 25, 2011):**
`matplotlib`'s interactive plotting system uses Tcl/Tk/Tkinter to provide a GUI. I installed the 64-bit Python, but I missed the following caveats in the Python.org download pages [link1](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.1/), [link2](http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/):
[image: http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.1/]
[image: http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/]
Therefore, I [deleted the 64-bit version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3819449/366309) and installed the 32-bit version. I would suggest to keep this question open just in case a 64-bit Tcl/Tk/Tkinter comes out for Python 2.7.

Comment: How did you install matplotlib? I don't think there's a binary installer for 64-bit OSX with python2.7 yet. It sounds like you have the 32-bit version installed on a 64-bit platform...

Comment: @Joe: Yes, that's right. I just replaced the 64-bit version with the 32-bit version. Question has been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an easy, out of the box solution: The Enthought Python Distribution 7.0 (64-bit academic version) worked great for me on Mac OS X Leopard, including Python 2.7, numpy, and matplotlib: https://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have wasted so much time trying to get stuff like this to work, I'd seen this enthought thing before but didn't realise it was free with a university email address

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg21310.html) mailing list message, the current matplotlib version from the installer is itself not compatible with the 64-bit version of Python from python.org, so you need the 32-bit version.

On the other hand, the [ScipySuperpack](http://fonnesbeck.github.com/ScipySuperpack/) installs a development version of matplotlib that works with 64 bit Python.

Answer (score 0):

I think the matplotlib package is not in your sys.path at all.Delete your matplotlib completely,and reinstall it again.

Answer (score 0):

With Python 2.7.2, you can use ActiveTcl, and use IDLE ...
See this note: http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/