# Reset easy_install after uninstalling Python on OS X

Tags: python, macos, reset, easy-install

I had 64-bit Python at first, then I installed BeautifulSoup using `easy_install`.

For some reason, I uninstalled 64-bit Python using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3819449/366309). Then I reinstalled the 32-bit version from Python.org. However:

```
Kit:~ Kit$ easy_install beautifulsoup
Searching for beautifulsoup
Best match: BeautifulSoup 3.2.0
Processing BeautifulSoup-3.2.0-py2.6.egg
BeautifulSoup 3.2.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/BeautifulSoup-3.2.0-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for beautifulsoup
Finished processing dependencies for beautifulsoup
```

This is a nasty sign that I haven't really found an easy way to **cleanly** uninstall Python on OS X. Besides, it mentions BeautifulSoup for Python **2.6**, but I have **2.7**. Sad `:(`

How do I reset `easy-install.pth`? I couldn't find it on Spotlight.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're running `easy_install` from the system Python 2.6.  Apple ships `easy_install` with the OS.  If you just installed Python 2.7 from python.org, you'll need to install [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) for that version.  (Note that you'll need to do this as root so it can write to `/usr/local/bin`.)  There are also Python version-suffixed `easy_install` versions, e.g. `easy_install-2.6`, so if for some reason you want to install a package in the system Python, then you can still do so.

Also, investigate [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/) which has an uninstall feature.

Comment: Note that ActivePython already includes distribute, pip and virtualenv.

Comment: python.org Pythons, by default, install Distutils scripts, like `easy_install`, in the framework `bin` directory, not `/usr/local/bin`.  `sudo` is generally not needed.

Comment: Ahh, I've only had experience with the Apple Python which uses `/usr/local/bin`. In that case you'll need to add the framework `bin` directory to your path (unless the installer does that?)