# pydev debugger: unable to find real location for python 2.7 after OS 10.8 upgrade

Tags: python, python-2.7, aptana, osx-mountain-lion

I just upgraded to OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion and having troubles understanding how the pydev debugger should work on Aptana 3.0.

In Aptana's preferences I have the python interpreter setup with a location of "/usr/bin/python". It states that the System libs are coming from "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/..."

When I start the debugger for my Google App Engine project within Aptana, the console logs:

```
pydev debugger: CRITICAL WARNING: This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled (internal generated filenames are not absolute)
pydev debugger: The debugger may still function, but it will work slower and may miss breakpoints.
```

It also states:

```
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: /Applications/Aptana Studio 3/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_2.2.2.2011100512/pysrc/pydevd.py
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py
...
```

And it lists out all of the .py files within the "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/" folder.

My app engine projects still loads, but I don't really understand why. What do I have to configure Aptana 3.0, and what's changed between my OSX 10.7 and 10.8 that made this critical warning come up?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had a very similar problem. It turned out that after upgrading to Mountain Lion, all the Python source files disappeared.

The solution was to install the "Command Line Tools" from Apple. Try this link:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=command%20line%20tools

Or go to https://developer.apple.com/opensource/ and find the "Command Line Tools"

Comment: Nice, installing Command Line Tools did the trick for me too. BTW, if you have Xcode 4.3 or higher, you can install it from within Xcode at Preferences>Download Pane>Install.

Comment: Also worked for me when I was getting this error message using debugger in Pycharm.