# What is the most painless way to remove one version of python and not the other on OSX 10.7.4?

Tags: python, macos, uninstallation

I accidentally installed 64 bit python a few weeks ago, and now all of my programs jump for it by default, instead of the more functional 32 bit python. Is there a painless way to uninstall 64 bit python but not 32?

Thanks!

Comment: typically `python` (the commandline option) is just a soft-link to a particular python implementation.  You should probably be able to re-point that link to the other version and then you're all set.

Comment: *How* did you install the extra python version? The default python that comes with OS X is usually not affected by additional python installations. Also, why not install additional modules you are missing in your 64-bit python?

Comment: If you used a python.org installer, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4/3819829#3819829

Comment: The program I am trying to use "Pronterface" simply does not work with 64 bit Python. I'm trying to test the software for a project, and I need 64 bit python out of the system. I know on windows, it's as simple as using an uninstaller, but on Mac I'm kind of lost.

Comment: The built-in Python on Lion is a universal build, which you can run in either 32-bit or 64-bit mode. And (unlike much earlier Apple versions) it's pretty up-to-date, and has no gaping holes in it, and comes with some very useful packages pre-installed.