# Revert from Python 2.7 to Python 2.6 in Mac OSX 10.6.8 doesn't work even though I've uninstalled Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I have mac OSX 10.6.8.  My system came with Python 2.6
I recently installed Python 2.7 but experienced many problems with it so decided to revert back to Python 2.6 by executing

```
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
```

I also removed Python 2.7 from my Applications folder.

Still, however, when I run

```
 $ python -V 

 Python 2.7.3
```

So I tried to make the default python 2.6 by running the following:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Version 2.6
```

However, still I see that my python version is 2.7.3

I seem incapable of even temporarily changing my version:

```
$ export VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION=2.6

$ python -V
Python 2.7.3
```

If it helps at all, this is what I get

```
$ which python
/opt/local/bin/python
```

I would really appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You likely already saw [this](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Mac/README) (search for 'Uninstalling a framework'), but it sounds like a few additional steps you could possibly take would be ensuring that the symlink `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current` points to your installed version of Python 2.6 and that you removed all Python 2.7 symlinks in /usr/local/bin.

I also just came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4) which does a much better job of answering than I just tried to do :)