# Installing Pandas on Mac OSX

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble installing the Python Pandas library on my Mac OSX computer.

I type the following in Terminal:

```
$ sudo easy_install pandas
```

But then I get the following:

```
Searching for pandas
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pandas/
Reading http://pandas.pydata.org
Reading http://pandas.sourceforge.net
Best match: pandas 0.9.0
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pandas/pandas-
0.9.0.zip#md5=04b1d8e11cc0fc30ae777499d89003ec
Processing pandas-0.9.0.zip
Writing /tmp/easy_install-ixjbQO/pandas-0.9.0/setup.cfg
Running pandas-0.9.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-ixjbQO/pandas-
0.9.0/egg-dist-tmp-EGREoT
warning: no files found matching 'setupegg.py'
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.png' found anywhere in distribution
unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I do have Xcode and gcc installed, however, gcc is only found when I type:

```
$ gcc
-bash: gcc: command not found

$ gcc-4.2
i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1: no input files
```

What should I do?

Comment: I also had trouble installing Pandas, but it was because I needed to upgrade numpy first.

Comment: Pandas runs on top of numpy; numpy is a dependency.

Answer (score 43):

Install `pip`.

Then install `pandas` with `pip`:

```
pip install pandas
```

Comment: I first had to run `sudo easy_install pip`, then this worked.

Comment: On my system pip was a FAR easier way to install pandas than the xcode route.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, after installing pip, i am able to install pandas

Comment: I had many `Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: ...`. Using '--user' however fixed this. `pip install --user pandas`

Answer (score 18):

You can install python with homebrew:

```
brew install python
```

Make sure that OSX uses the correct path:

```
which python
```

Then you can use the pip tool to install pandas:

```
pip install pandas
```

Make sure that all dependencies are installed. I followed this tutorial: http://penandpants.com/2013/04/04/install-scientific-python-on-mac-os-x/

Works fine on my machine.

Answer (score 9):

You need to install XCode AND you need to make sure you install the **command line tools** for XCode so you can get gcc.

Comment: Agreed.  This is what I had to do to get Pandas installed correctly.

Comment: this answer should be accepted. works perfectly. note: be careful you download the proper xcode command line tool for you OS.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
pip3 install pandas
```

from terminal. Maybe your original pip install pandas is referencing anaconda distribution

Answer (score 4):

I would recoment using macport or fink to install pandas:

1. Install XCode from App Store, this will install 3 compilers, clang, gcc ("apple") and gcc ("normal")
2. Install macports (www.macports.org) or fink (www.finkproject.org)
3. Never use your mac python again, and install all python modules trough the fink/macport and enjoy it taking care dependencies for you.

Installing pandas in macports is as simple as:
    sudo port install py27-pandas

you usualy install macport in /opt/local and fink in /sw, I would advice (though this may be bad advice) you to symlink your fink/mac ports python to your system python as follows such that:
/usr/bin/python -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7

Answer (score 4):

In Mac terminal (we can launch Mac **Terminal** by searching in spotlight search *Command + space*) Now, use  the command:

> pip3 install pandas

As I'm using **Python Version 3** I need to use pip3 install pandas.

If you are using **python version 2** than use Command:

> pip install pandas

Make sure **pip** is already installed in the device

Answer (score 2):

`pip install pandas` works fine with `pip 18.0` on `macOS 10.13.6`.
 In addition, to work with Xlsx files, you will need `xlrd` installed.

Answer (score 1):

Not an innovative way but below two steps might save a ton of time and energy.

1. **Updating (Installing Command Line Tool) Code.**

This can be done by openinig XCode -> Menu -> Preference -> Components -> Command Line Tool

2. **Removing all but Python 2.7**

I did installed different instances of python at different time and removing all but 2.7 was helpful in my case. Note : You may have to install modules after doing it. So get ready with pip/easy_install/ports.

Uninstall can be done with super easy steps mentioned in following link.

[How to uninstall Python 2.7 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4/3819829#3819829)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a sim link

```
$ ln -s gcc gcc-4.2
```

This should tell your terminal to call gcc-4.2 when you run $ gcc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install newest version of xCode from appStore. It contains the compiler for C(gcc) and C++(g++) for mac. Then you can install pandas without any problem. Use the following commands in terminal:

1. xcode-select --install
2. pip3 install pandas

It might take some time as it installs other packages too. Please be patient.

Answer (score 0):

Write down this and try to import pandas again!

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install pandas
```

It worked for me, hope will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

for Mac run the given command in terminal

```
sudo easy_install pip
pip3 install pandas
```

if you want to install pandas profiling then run

```
pip3 install pandas-profiling
```

Answer (score -1):

pip install worked for me, and it failed with a permission issue, which was resolved when I used

sudo pip install pandas

I see that the best sudo workaround is from /tmp: [Is it acceptable and safe to run pip install under sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028648/is-it-acceptable-and-safe-to-run-pip-install-under-sudo)

Comment: I would like to ask why this answer was down voted? It also did not work for me and my (and I think many other people's) reflex was to use sudo.

Comment: You'd better not use sudo for python package install in mac

Comment: can you explain more ? Why do you think sudo pip on Mac is not good ? I see various discussions around this, but nothing solid.