# Cannot find module cv2 when using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I have installed [OpenCV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) on the Occidentalis operating system (a variant of Raspbian) on a Raspberry Pi, using [this script](https://github.com/jayrambhia/Install-OpenCV/blob/master/Ubuntu/opencv_latest.sh) by jayrambhia. It installed version 2.4.5.

When I try `import cv2` in a Python program, I get the following message:

```
pi@raspberrypi~$ python cam.py
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "cam.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

The file `cv2.so` is stored in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/...`

There are also folders in `/usr/local/lib` called `python3.2` and `python2.6`, in case that is relevant.

How can I fix the problem? Is this caused by a path misconfiguration?

Comment: try : python --version . if it says 3.2, then you got a hint. try to locate the 2.7 executable, and call that with an absolute path

Comment: For macOS 10.12 and python 3 the simple command below worked to resolve the error: pip install opencv-python Refer: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python

Comment: If you are using macOS Catalina, maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/61578366/11559619

Comment: `pip install opencv-python==4.6.0.66`

Comment: My solution (after 2 hours!!!) was copying file cv2.pyd (from Python folder) to C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

Don't know how it works. Sometimes you should not just follow official instructions but also do analogous things with both Python/pip and Anaconda/conda. I already met this while trying to install Tensorflow.

Answer (score 549):

First do run these commands inside Terminal/CMD:

```
conda update anaconda-navigator  
conda update navigator-updater
```

Then the issue for the instruction below will be resolved

For windows if you have anaconda installed, you can simply do

```
pip install opencv-python
```

or

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv
```

if you are on linux you can do :

```
pip install opencv-python
```

or

```
conda install opencv
```

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872683/unable-to-install-cv2-on-windows#comment68960647_40872683) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2/41895783#comment69457795_35546806)

For python3.5+ check these links : [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42540015/2736559) , [Link4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30686903/2736559)

Update:
if you use anaconda, you may simply use this as well (and hence don't need to add menpo channel):

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

Comment: for linux you should type 'pip install opencv-python' or 'sudo pip install opencv-python'

Comment: You got the command wrong. It is `sudo pip3 install opencv-python`. Also, for linux, you must run it as `sudo pip3 install opencv-python` for python 3 and `sudo pip install opencv-python` for python 2. You do not need the sudo at the beginning of the command if you do `sudo -i` forst or are running as root in some manner.

Comment: If facing problems while installing, make sure you have the newest version of pip `pip install --upgrade pip` this was my wattle

Comment: `pip install opencv-python` works for me and I don't have Anaconda.  Just FYI for anyone else who comes here.

Comment: @tilper: Yes, pip is also shipped with Python as well. I did'nt know this at the time

Comment: @vinuVish: I'm glad to hear that ;-)

Comment: @OzRadiano [`sudo pip install` should **not** be used](https://askubuntu.com/q/802544/253474). [Is it acceptable and safe to run pip install under sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15028648/995714). This is recommended by [scipy](https://www.scipy.org/install.html) and [python.org](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-you-can-run-python-from-the-command-line)

Comment: `pip install opencv-python` worked in MacBook anaconda environment

Comment: pip installation is the only one that worked on my Linux.

Comment: Before those commands, please install anaconda3 from their site https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/index.html

Comment: `conda install -c conda-forge opencv` works for me. Thanks you.

Comment: `pip install opencv-python` command worked for me in anacoda, Thank you.

Answer (score 95):

This happens when python cannot refer to your default site-packages folder where you have kept the required python files or libraries

Add these lines in the code:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

or before running the python command in bash move to */usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages* directory. This is a work around if you don't want to add any thing to the code.

Comment: Are you working on windows?This path look like at linux system.

Comment: the question was about Raspbian OS , which is Linux .

Comment: Worked for me on mac machine

Comment: it works for one session, but if I exit and re-launch python, I have to do it again. how to save this modification?

Comment: I get "ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import" when I do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did u install numpy?

Comment: Thanks, but why does this happen?

Comment: Modifying `sys.path` to include folders for *other Python installations* is definitely not the right way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 64):

I solved my issue using the following command :

```
conda install opencv
```

Comment: If you've got Anaconda Python installed, this is the command you're looking for.

Comment: I tried this today on a Windows 64-bit 2.7 conda environment and got a `PackageNotFound error`

Comment: What did work was `conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv`

Comment: `pip install opencv-python==4.6.0.66`

Answer (score 48):

Try to add the following line in `~/.bashrc`

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me when used: export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/python/2.7:$PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 40):

Python3.x User

```
sudo pip3 install opencv-python
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/802544/is-sudo-pip-install-still-a-broken-practice

Comment: It works for me too. Thank you! (cuda 2204, cudnn 8.5.0, python 3.10.3)

Comment: Works like a charm, I love u (Ubuntu 22, Python 3.11.4

Answer (score 37):

For Windows 10 and Python 3.6, this worked for me

`pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Comment: Worked for me on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) too

Comment: This solved my problem on Ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 29):

```
pip install opencv-python
```

or

```
pip install opencv-python3
```

will definitely work fine.

Answer (score 28):

None of the above answers worked for me. I was going crazy until I found this solution below!

Simply run:

```
sudo apt install python-opencv
```

Comment: sudo apt install python3-opencv for Ubuntu 20 and probably others in future

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package python-opencv` showing this error

Answer (score 23):

I solved my issue using the following command :

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 16):

I solve it by running:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 11):

I solve this by run code `pip install opencv_contrib_python`

Answer (score 9):

I have come accross same as this problem i installed cv2 by

```
pip install cv2
```

However when i import cv2 module it displayed no module named cv2 error.

Then i searched and find `cv2.pyd` files in my computer and i copy and paste to site-packages directory

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
```

then i closed and reopened existing application, it worked.

**EDIT**
I will tell how to install `cv2` correctly.

**1.** Firstly install numpy on your computer by

```
pip install numpy
```

**2.** Download [opencv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/) from internet (almost 266 mb).

 I download `opencv-2.4.12.exe` for python 2.7. Then install this opencv-2.4.12.exe file.
 
I extracted to `C:\Users\harun\Downloads` to this folder.
After installation go look for `cv2.py` into the folders.
For me

```
C:\Users\harun\Downloads\opencv\build\python\2.7\x64
```

in this folder take the`cv2.pyd` and copy it in to the

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
```

now you can able to use `cv2` in you python scripts.

Comment: I don't think the package `cv2` installed through `pip`has anything to do with `openCV`, you confirm ?

Comment: @Newben sorry for late response. in  EDIT  part i talk about how to install opencv correctly. i wish it will help you if you have not solve the problem

Comment: Using `pip install opencv-python` should work when trying to install via `pip`.

Comment: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cv2`

Answer (score 9):

Easy

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 7):

For **python3x** users

```
$ sudo pip3 install opencv-python
```

For **python2x** users

```
$ sudo pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: This answer didn't work for me on raspbian, it installed fine but didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

**IF YOU ARE BUILDING FROM SCRATCH, GO THROUGH THIS**

You get `No module named cv2.cv`.
Son, you did all step right, since your `sudo make install` gave no errors.

However look at this step

```
$ cd ~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
$ ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so cv2.so
```

**THE VERY IMPORTANT STEP OF ALL THESE IS TO LINK IT.**

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so cv2.so 
or 
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so cv2.so
```

The moment you choose wise linking, or by brute force just find the cv2.so file if that exist or not

Here I am throwing my output.

```
    Successfully installed numpy-1.15.3
(cv) demonLover-desktop:~$ cd ~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
(cv) demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so cv2.so
(cv) demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
numpy      1.15.3 
pip        18.1   
setuptools 40.5.0 
wheel      0.32.2 
(cv) demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
>>> 
[2]+  Stopped                 python
(cv) demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/c
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/c': No such file or directory
(cv) demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
(cv) demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ deactivate 
demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ls
cv2.so  easy_install.py  easy_install.pyc  numpy  numpy-1.15.3.dist-info  pip  pip-18.1.dist-info  pkg_resources  setuptools  setuptools-40.5.0.dist-info  wheel  wheel-0.32.2.dist-info
demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ls -l  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
total 0
demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ls
cv2.so  easy_install.py  easy_install.pyc  numpy  numpy-1.15.3.dist-info  pip  pip-18.1.dist-info  pkg_resources  setuptools  setuptools-40.5.0.dist-info  wheel  wheel-0.32.2.dist-info
demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ workon cv
(cv) demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
>>> 
[3]+  Stopped                 python
(cv) demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ find / -name "cv2.so"
find: ‘/lost+found’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/udisks2’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/docker’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/exim4’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/lightdm’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/cups/certs’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/sudo’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/samba/ncalrpc/np’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/postgresql/9.5-main.pg_stat_tmp’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/postgresql/10-main.pg_stat_tmp’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/lvm’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/systemd/inaccessible’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/lock/lvm’: Permission denied
find: ‘/root’: Permission denied
^C
(cv) demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ sudofind / -name "cv2.so"
sudofind: command not found
(cv) demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ^C
(cv) demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ sudo find / -name "cv2.so"
[sudo] password for app: 
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
^C
(cv) demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ sudo find /usr/ -name "cv2.so"
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so
^C
(cv) demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ccv2.so cv2.so
click/                        clonevirtualenv.pyc           configparser-3.5.0.dist-info/ configparser.py               cv2.so                        cycler.py
clonevirtualenv.py            concurrent/                   configparser-3.5.0-nspkg.pth  configparser.pyc              cycler-0.10.0.dist-info/      cycler.pyc
(cv) demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so cv2.so
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'cv2.so': File exists
(cv) demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ rm cv2.so 
(cv) demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so cv2.so
(cv) demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ls
cv2.so  easy_install.py  easy_install.pyc  numpy  numpy-1.15.3.dist-info  pip  pip-18.1.dist-info  pkg_resources  setuptools  setuptools-40.5.0.dist-info  wheel  wheel-0.32.2.dist-info
(cv) demonLover-desktop:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>>
```

My step will only help, if your built is done right.

Comment: Only with the help of @TheExorcist could solve this

Comment: Glad to help you @RodneySalcedo , but it is sin while linking, we commit unconsciously.

Comment: Thanks, but why doesn't this happen automatically?

Comment: @Cypher nothing happens automatically, that's why exorcist exists

Comment: I was hoping that building OpenCV would automatically add the library files to the Python distribution it found on the system, but it seems not to do that

Comment: @Cypher yes you can do that but you need to put a constraint of version of library else cmake build gonna give you error depending on sys arch, mostly building should be secondary pref.

Answer (score 5):

If want to install opencv in virtual environment. 
Run command in terminal for getting virtual environment list.

```
conda env list
```

or 
jupyter notebook command is

```
!conda env list
```

Then update your anaconda.

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
conda update navigator-updater
```

Install opencv in your selected environment path.

```
conda install -c ['environment path'] opencv
```

Juypter notebook

```
!conda install --yes --prefix ['environment path'] opencv
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a virtual environment and then install open-cv there.
It worked for me. And, it is best practice to create a virtual environment.
Create a virtual environment:

```
python3 -m venv env
```

Activating virtual environment
For Linux:

```
source env/bin/activate
```

Install OpenCV and other modules now.

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Above will work for linux.
Similarly, you can create virtual environment for windows and then install opencv
More on Virtual Environment:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-python-virtual-environment-windows-linux/

Answer (score 1):

The best way for me to solve this problem was to install `python3-venv` and create a new environment, then install my packages, because any method presented here could not solve the problem and always resulted in the same error. Maybe my solution could be helpful to others:

```
1- install python3-venv
2- Create and activate new venv
3- pip3 install opencv-python
```

Comment: and it should be run with 'python3 cam.py'

Answer (score 1):

I had opencv installed and I tried to upgrade pip and opencv both but i didnt work.
this worked for me

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python<4.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
sudo ldconfig

sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf
```

and add this following line in the `opencv.conf` not in the command window

```
/usr/local/lib
```

Then:

```
sudo ldconfig

sudo nano /etc/bash.bashrc
```

and add this two lines in the `bash.bashrc` not in the command window

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig       
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

at last reboot your Pi `sudo reboot now`

and try `import cv2`

Comment: Can you please explain why these steps? How they are related to cv2?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just couldn't figure it out with opencv2 and opencv3 installed into /opt/opencv and opencv3 respectively. Turned out that bloody anaconda install of opencv in my home directory was first on path and mangled opencv. Removed it and started using /opt/opencv3/lib as defined in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf. Worked perfectly first go. Do you have anaconda installed? Could be the issue.

Comment: Can you tell me how you did it?

Answer (score 0):

Another way I got opencv to install and work was inside visual studio 2017 community.
Visual studio has a nice python environment with debugging.
So from the vs python env window I searched and added opencv. 
Just thought I would share because I like to try things different ways and on different computers.

[image: VisualStudio2017 python environments with opencv]

Answer (score 0):

I know you had the issue with Occidentalis, but I had the issue on Windows too, and I didn't found anything helpful. So if you have windows, and you've installed opencv, but you still get an Import error, this method will maybe solve the issue.

I managed to solve the issue, by reactivating anaconda.

First I deleted your\path\to\anaconda3 and your\path\to\anaconda3\Scripts from PATH (you will need these later, so remember these paths)

Then if you run python from cmd it will say:

```
Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated. Libraries may fail to load. To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation.
```

Then in Anaconda prompt I ran these:

```
your\path\to\anconda3\Scripts\activate base 
conda activate --stack your\path\to\anaconda3
```

I'm not sure about is this the easiest way to reactivate anaconda, but this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is for those who are using ubuntu to run their script.py
you have to copy cv2.so under your python pachkages dir and then resourcing your bachrc.
here:

```
sudo cp -rfv /home/<user>/<your opencv file dir>/lib/cv2.so  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

Answer (score -1):

This Question Have easy Solutions

1. Install Anconda Navigator
2. Then Go to Environment And Search "**Opencv**"
3. Add the Tick Mark and Apply Install
4. Finally slove the Problem

[image: Like That]

Answer (score -1):

I worked with the code below and it worked perfectly well;

pip install opencv-python==4.6.0.66[image]