# No module named cv2

Tags: python

I am getting error

```
No module named cv2
```

Can you please guide what command should I type to install CV2 (sudo qpt-get install ..?)
Thank you

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vtest.avi')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What version of linux are you using? Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2

Comment: I followed the instructions from here http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

Comment: @Paul Lo Although my problem has solved but can you please tell me how do i check version of Linux

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham I don't know why this one was not working at my side

Comment: This article might help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/how-can-i-get-distribution-name-and-version-number-in-a-simple-shell-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install python-openCV
```

Comment: Sorry to ask you incomplete question, both machines are directly connected to each other, and I know the password of my both machines. I want to put all info(host-name, IP, password) in program so that It will not ask for more info during program execution.
Thank You

Comment: I've posted a solution for this problem where you have asked it. Hole it works for you...

Answer (score 5):

use `pip` command line:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use conda install cv2:

```
conda install -c opencv3
```