# how to "install" custom python module made by boost.python

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have made a `.so` module with boost.python and can import it from local folder.

```
|--my_class.so
|--python_code.py
```

in python_code.py

```
from my_class import *
```

Obviously if I put `python_code.py` in a different folder, `from my_class import *` would fail.

I am wondering if there is a way that I can "install" `my_class.so` in a gobal package location that I can import it from any python script. So `my_class` has the same status as packages like `numpy` .

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to move the .so file somewhere on your python library path. On my machine one example is the directory /usr/lib/python2.7

One way you might consider doing this is with a setup.py file, which can be configured to handle your build and install.

In the past I've sometimes just copied it there by hand for testing or put a something such as below into a Makefile so it copies after compile:

```
#
#   Install the python module
#
install: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MyModule.so

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MyModule.so: python-module
    cp $(BIN)MyModule.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MyModule.so
```

Comment: I found [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2), I think I have to add it manually. Does it load automatically for you?

Comment: Yeah, if the module is in the pythonpath it will load. Check the version of python you are using and add the .so file to one of the directories such as /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/*.so