# OpenCV for Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have searched quite a bit regarding this and I've tried some of these methods myself but I'm unable to work with OpenCV.So can anyone of you help me install OpenCV for python 3.5.1?

I'm using anaconda along with Pycharm in windows

Or is this not possible and i have to use python 2.7?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Python 3.4 is supported by OpenCV 3.x, not sure if there would be any issues with Python 3.5.1. Link to installation instructions for various platforms: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/table_of_content_introduction/table_of_content_introduction.html

Comment: do both conda and pip install it will work fine

Answer (score 8):

1. First you need to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable, which you can download from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587.
2. Then you can download the wheel file from
   http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv. 
   Make sure you download the file which
   corresponds to your python version. For example: my python version
   is 3.5 so I downloaded
   opencv_python-3.2.0+contrib-cp**35**-cp35m-win_amd64.whl.
3. And install it with "pip install filename".

Comment: whats the difference between the contrib version vs the non-contrib version?

Comment: The contrib version does get installed on Python 3.5.1.Do try it.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who would like to install OpenCV on Python 3.5.1,use this library called

> opencv-contrib-python

This library works for Python 3.5.1

Answer (score 3):

Quick solution for anaconda users - Go to anaconda prompt run -

```
conda install opencv
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know how we can help you.
Because you didn't specify the OS.
As far as I know, there are many resources in [answers.opencv.org](http://answers.opencv.org).
A question similar what you asked is answered [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/81245/opencv-310-on-python-351-with-windows-7-64bit/).

Comment: The OS which i am using is WIndows 8.1 64 bit

Comment: I think you should provide more information, which method you follow and what did you find .... etc.

Answer (score 1):

For OS:Windows 10 and Python version: 3.5.1 & 3.6, this worked for me

pip install opencv-contrib-python