# python: pip install opencv-python give me error

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.8

I am install python 3.8.0v and run pip install opencv-python its give me error.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293933/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-opencv-python)

Comment: Python supported version - 2.7 3.4 3.5 3.6 3.7

Answer (score 2):

It seems opencv does not work on Python 3.8 yet, see this issue: https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/253

Answer (score 1):

You can also refer to this question also [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35466429/opencv-for-python-3-5-1)

What you can also try is installing opencv-contrib-python using pip.I have used the above solutions earlier and they worked for me in Python 3.5.1.They might also work for Python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the latest version of python. Or u can upgrade your pip ...
Or try installing opencv-contrib-python using pip.

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)