# importing a python lib with an so file

Tags: python, import, python-import

I am new to `Python` and I have installed `OpenCV` library which ends with `cv2.so` file installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. When I try to import this library in my code with `import cv2`, I get

```
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

How can I manage that

Comment: I am not sure but maybe that help You: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2

Comment: @MartinP thank you very much !!