# Python Import cv2 error in jupyter works on mac terminal

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I am having difficulty **importing cv2 on jupyter notebook**. However, when I enter:

```
import cv2
```

in the mac terminal there is no error.

I referenced  [post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory) to identify that jupyter notebook refers to python3.5 file path where as mac terminal where the import works fine refers to python 2.7 file path.

I entered the below in jupyter notebook as referenced in  [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2) to solve the issue, but I'm still getting an error:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
import cv2
```

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use a module for python 2.7 in python 3.5, so you'll either have to install cv2 in your python3 environment or get jupyter to use python2