# Unable to install cv2 on windows

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to install `opencv` in `python` on my windows machine but I am unable to do so. I have python `2.7.11::Anaconda 2.4.1 <32-bit>`

Here is what I have tried till now -

1. `pip install cv2` on command line gives the error :

> could not find a
> version that satisfies the requirement cv2

2. I downloaded the package from sourceforge site, followed the steps
   and pasted cv2.pyd in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` but still it is
   not working. I get the following error message

> ImportError: No
> module named cv2

(I already have numpy installed and it works just fine).

Comment: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv

Comment: Also, it's `pip install opencv-python`, not `pip install cv2`.

Comment: Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z78zbnLlPUA&index=1&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDdttJXlLtAJxJetJcqmqlQq)

Answer (score 43):

```
pip install opencv-python
```

you can type this instead of

```
pip install cv2
```

it also works with anaconda pro

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
pip install opencv-python==4.3.0.36
```

Comment: why specifically this version?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the error.

If you are using python version 3 , sometimes you have to use pip3.

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

[image]

Make sure you are using python 3 , it won't work for python 2.

Answer (score 0):

So I was using PyCharm, and what worked for me was to install it directly from file->settings, Project:your-project-name->Python Interpreter list

Comment: This seems like your pycharm project is configured to run with a different python version than pip uses by default

Answer (score 0):

You can use the:

***pip install opencv-contrib-python***

You can also use the *pip3 install opencv-python command*