# Can't import cv2 in raspberry pi 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I have followed this [guide](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/) to install Open CV on my Raspberry pi3, with noobs on it, for both python2 and python3, but still can't import cv2 in python, (and can't find it when running pip freeze as well).

What might be the problem? (suggestions, tests that will help me figure it out)
I've tried import cv2 and got the following output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "stdin", line 1, in module 
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'

Comment: what command have you tried and what was the error you got?

Comment: @user3299379 just edited the question accordingly

Comment: I wouldn't call this a duplicate as this question doesn't seem to have an accepted answer but see if any of it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2