# error: no module name cv2, how to solve this error while importing opencv in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, opencv

I have install opencv using this code:

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv
```

and when i try to import cv2 in python2/3 is gives this error

```
import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

Comment: which is your default python? are using virtual env?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV - cannot find module cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2)