# ImportError: No module named 'cv2' Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-import

I have such a problem

```
(face_det) user@pc:~$ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Apr 22 2017, 00:00:00) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'cv2
```

I don't have it on python2:

```
(face_det) user@pc:~$ python2
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import cv2
>>>
```

In spite of  the fact, that I have opencv (I've also tryed to remove it and install then):

```
(face_det) user@pc:~$ pip3 install opencv
Requirement already satisfied: opencv in ./.virtualenvs/face_det/lib/python3.5/site-packages
(face_det) user@pc:~$ conda install opencv
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/pc/anaconda3:
#
opencv                    3.2.0               np112py27_0    conda-forge
```

Comment: There appears to be an [open issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8039) on their GitHub about this and some suggestions to fix it.

Comment: is that a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think they're referencing different issues. I'm not sure it's safe to dupe, the issue I linked to suggest that there may be dependency problems.

Comment: Ok, not abusing my gold badge powers and not closing as a duplicate. Note that this problem never gets old :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it is of course your prerogative :P But on this one, I think there may be a genuine conflict somewhere.

Answer (score 44):

Try

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

to get the `cv2`. I'm not sure when `opencv-python` became available. I'd been building opencv by hand, but when I looked a few weeks ago, there it was. I'm using `cv2` with Python3 in a VM that's running `ubuntu/trusty64`.

Comment: pip install opencv-python is also ok in verison above Python-3.10

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
sudo python3.5 -m pip install opencv-python
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 3):

On Windows you can try this:

```
python3 -m pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on Linux judging by `pc:~$`

Try installing from the following *link*:

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

### It worked for me, hope the same for you!

Answer (score 0):

Your conda openCV is installed for use by your home python2.7. Your opencv installed via pip3 is for use in your face_det virtual environment. It doesn't look like you're in that virtual environment when you opened python3 in the first code block. Try

```
source activate face_det
python3
import cv2
```

Comment: I just didn't  selected that text, I am in it

Comment: when you're in the face_det venv what's the output of  `which python3 ` ?

Comment: /home/user/.virtualenvs/face_det/bin/python3

Comment: now that you edited the question it clearly shows you weren't in the virtual environment, was that on purpose?

Comment: I would suggest just using a [docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/victorhcm/opencv/) container and share your webcam devices if you're using linux, if you're on mac try a homebrew install

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the same error. In my case, I was using PyCharm. The problem was that the project's interpreter was pointing to a different installation of Python.

In my system, I had four versions of python (eg. python3 installed in a `python36` folder, another python in an `anaconda3` folder and others). In my PyCharm project, when I examined my settings (under File->Settings->Project:xxxx ->Project interpreter), I found that they were pointing to the interpreter in the `anaconda3` folder.

However, my default `pip` installed the `opencv-python` module under the `python36` folder. Therefore, I just had to change the project interpreter to point to the python installed in `python36` folder and it worked.

If you would like to keep using Anaconda3 then you have to browse to the `anaconda3` folder and run `pip install opencv-python` in that folder.