# Unable to import 'cv2'

Tags: python

I hade this problem while writing my program.
Unable to import 'cv2'

when I run the program this error occurs:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'cv2'
File "C:\Users\subhadra\Desktop\Programs\OpenCV.py", line 1, in <module>
import cv2
```

I already have installed opencv, numpy, Matplotlib.
but also i didn't work. Please some one give me solution for this.

Comment: Try downloading it from a virtual environment in python version 3.86 if you are already using python 3.86 then it might be problem with your os

Answer (score 0):

> pip install opencv-python

try this

Comment: Also see this previous answer. Could be a conflict between your OS version and opencv version. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643650/importerror-no-module-named-cv2-python3