# ImportError: No module named cv2 error upon running .py file in terminal

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I am having trouble running a python script file that contains `import opencv` command. Upon running the file, it gives the following error:
`ImportError: No module named cv2`

I then ran `pip install python-opencv` but it gave `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-opencv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-opencv` error.

Does anyone know what the issue might be? I was able to run this python file at first but I haven't been able to run after that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV - cannot find module cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2)

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar well I did try the commands stated in the verified solution but the issue still persists

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/blue-ice/e6bc36a906c86070eb50

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar shall I run the python file after executing those commands? I tried and now I am getting `ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import` error :/

Answer (score 1):

Package name is wrong `pip install opencv-python` Should work.

Comment: Running this command gives error `DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.`

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. Tried different things. But finally

**conda install opencv**

solved the issue for me.

Comment: I think he is not using anaconda so it might not help.