# 'no module named cv2' import error on pytorch

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I am currently studying Pytorch and trying to use the `cv2` module. I am using Jupyter notebook and Windows.

I have installed `opencv` like this:

```
!pip install opencv-python
```

When I choose the kernel (by change kernel option) `Python3` and import `cv2` then there is no problem.

But when I choose the kernel `Pytorch` and import `cv2`, then there is an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

This must be a basic question but I can't find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2):

> First do run these commands
>
> `$ conda update anaconda-navigator`
>
> `$ conda update navigator-updater`
>
> then the issue for the instruction below will be resolved

**For windows** if you have `anaconda` installed, you can simply do:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

or

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv
```

**If you're on linux** you can do :

```
pip install opencv-python
```

or

```
conda install opencv
```

Answer (score -1):

If you run `pip install opencv` failed. You can download the `whl` file in
[here](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#files) and then install it locally:

```
pip install opencv_python-4.5.5.64-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: you should not download wheels from PyPI. simply run `pip install opencv-python`, which does the same, without extra steps