# Importing OpenCV - import cv2 or cv3, and why does the directory matter?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to use OpenCV for Python 3 for the first time. To install, I simply typed `pip3 install opencv-python` into the terminal. When I do this, I see in Finder (I'm on a Mac), that in `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`, I now have a new folder called `"cv2"`.

This is strange. Why isn't it cv3, as I used pip3? I do not know.

When I try to `import cv2` from `python3`, it says `No module named 'cv2'`. Luckily [StackOverflow already has a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2): if I first change directories like:

`cd /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`

then I will be able to open `cv2`. **I do not know why this step is necessary for OpenCV.** I don't have to do this to `import numpy` for example; `numpy` does not care what directory I start from, and it is listed like just another module like cv2.

Anyways, I change directory to `site-packages`, start `python3`, and I `import cv2`. Now there is a new error. This time `cv2` is found, but it says:

```
from .cv2 import *  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2.cv2'
```

For the record, I also have Python 2.7. If I try `cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and then start Python 2.7, I can import `cv2`. This is ok, but I want to use OpenCV with Python3.

Let me summarize.

(1) How can I get cv2 or cv3 to import when I start from any directory? Is this ever possible?

(2) How can I get cv3 for python3? cv2 seems to be problematic in python3 because because there is no `cv2.cv2`

Answer (score 3):

The only thing we need to know here is, that 2 in cv2 is not a version. cv2 uses API of C++ while cv uses C API. Version of it is constantly updating being inside CV2.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "cv3".

"cv2" stands for the API version, not the library version.

API Version 1 was for C (and Python). API version 2 is C++ (and Python).

API Version 2 exists since library version 2.0.

API Version 1 was removed step by step throughout library version 3.x. It is no longer available in library version 4.0.

If you installed the package but your Python can't `import cv2 as cv` (the officially recommended import statement), then you either installed the package into a virtual environment or you have multiple pythons and you installed it in a different python from the one you're trying to import it into.

Answer (score -1):

There is no cv3 there's only **import cv2** that opencv older or latest that is updated for old python or latest.