# Jupyter Notebook can not import cv2

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am new to Jupyter Notebook and I was following a youtube tutorial. Currently I am using Jupyter Notebook in the browser version. In the first line of the code (from the youtube video) it asked me to import cv2. After I run it, it shows this error

---

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 
>   ----> 2 import cv2
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

Can anyone let me know what is my mistake and how can I solve it?
Thankyou so much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV - cannot find module cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2)

Comment: it shows that you dont have the cv2 module installed. Have you tried to install? you can try : pip install opencv-python

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't install OpenCv yet.
Just install it with pip.

```
pip install opencv-python
```