# In my project OpenCV is not working gives:- cannot find module cv2 in Linux

Tags: python, linux, opencv

I am getting the OpenCV cv2 module cann't find error in my project.
I have tried below commands

```
sudo pip install cv2

sudo pip3 install cv2
```

Comment: Going to need a bit more information in order to help. And this is a very very common problem so you will probably be flagged for duplicate

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/15/how-to-install-opencv-4-on-ubuntu/) explaining the steps to install opencv on ubuntu. Granted the tutorial is a little complicated as it uses virtual systems but it does go through all the steps.

Comment: I am using it for Image Processing in OpenCV. But openCV is giving errot cannot find module cv2 in Linux.
Thanks for the link I am trying it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find module cv2 when using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you have to input :

```
sudo pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

For more tutorial installing `opencv` using `pip` : https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

For more tutorial installing `opencv` from source : https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/15/how-to-install-opencv-4-on-ubuntu/