# 'opencv-python' installed but still shows 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named cv2 '

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I have run the command

```
pip3 list
```

It shows that I have already installed these versions of OpenCV

> opencv-contrib-python    4.1.2.30
>   opencv-python            4.2.0.32

But whenever I import cv2 it shows the error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

Comment: Are you running   pip3 list  and import in the same environment ?

Comment: Yes I am using python3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module cv2 when using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/cannot-find-module-cv2-when-using-opencv)

Answer (score 0):

If you had a previous version installed. Uninstall it first and try installing it. See the instructions here:
https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

Comment: Can't you see that I have the latest version installed!

Comment: Hey, I understand that you have the latest version. I asked you if this was fresh installation or your were trying to install in a existing environment. Installing over an older version can create conflict which could be the reason.