# No module named 'cv2' on Anaconda 3.8.3

Tags: python, anaconda, opencv

I just Installed the latest Anaconda 3.8.3 with conda version 4.8.3
right away after I installed Anaconda, I use Jupyter Notebook then type

```
import cv2
```

it says

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> ----> 1 import cv2
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

then based on :
[Cannot find module cv2 when using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/cannot-find-module-cv2-when-using-opencv)

someone suggested trying

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv
```

from the Anaconda Prompt

[image: prompt result]

Is there any other way to install cv2?

Comment: Try `pip install opencv` in corresponding conda env

Comment: `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`

Comment: I tried `pip install opencv` and `conda install -c conda-forge opencv` and still failed with the same result @Sociopath and @nirmal

Comment: You need to be an administrator to install packages with your current setup. You should launch the Anaconda Prompt in Administrator mode. If you don't know how to do that, it would probably be best to uninstall and re-install Anaconda, clicking the box to install it only for your own user account.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just open your command prompt with run as administrator. And try,

`conda install -c conda-forge opencv`

Comment: This did the trick, though I don't understand why `conda install opencv` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when using the command conda install -c menpo opencv

Specifications:

- opencv -> python[version='2.7.*|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']
  Your python: python=3.8
  .So,by using pip it got solved.

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

This one works on MacOS and Windows.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you may be able to solve the problem with this command.

```
 pip install opencv-python
```

If not, I think maybe the virtual environment is set up incorrectly. Make sure the package is installed on the appropriate interpreter.