# Opencv visible in environment, but not usable in Spyder

Tags: import, anaconda, spyder, opencv, python

I am trying to import cv2 in Spyder. When I check my environment in Anaconda, it seems to be there (see [packages in environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EgEI.png)). However, when I want to import cv2 in Spyder (opened from that same environment) I get the following error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
[error when importing cv2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d99Zq.png)

I hope someone can help me. I work on mscOS Catalina, Python version is 3.7.3 and I am not sure as how to check my opencv version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module cv2 when using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/cannot-find-module-cv2-when-using-opencv)

Comment: A link a click further might, trying it now, thank you for responding!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out my environment was running on Python 3.7.3. and I simply had to create an environment running on Python 2.7