# Automatic Number Plate Recognition using Tensorflow and EasyOCR: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I have an error when running on jupyter notebook

```
 import cv2 
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    %matplotlib inline
```

And here's the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_24728/2850105776.py in <module>
----> 1 import cv2
      2 import numpy as np
      3 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
      4 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

May I know how to solve it? Thanks

I was following this tutorial video on creating the project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-4p_QgrdbE Automatic Number Plate Recognition using Tensorflow and EasyOCR Full Course in 2 Hours | Python

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the module and that the version of python you are using is compatible with it.
This site might be of help: [Cannot find module cv2 when using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/cannot-find-module-cv2-when-using-opencv)

Comment: I had installed the module but not sure why there's an error when I reopen jupyter notebook and run the codes.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Just python, which is downloaded from python.org

Comment: It is Version 3.9

Comment: I just a method to solve the problem, which is pip install opencv-contrib-python and now it runs smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, just install the package `pip install opencv-python` or if you are using anaconda `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`

Comment: Ok, so I have installed before running the codes above but after I had closed the jupyter notebook and reopen, it's unable to identify the cv2 location.

Comment: Should I add pip install opencv-python in front of this code in jupyter notebook or cmd?

Comment: just add the library in your command prompt, I suggest you to use virtual environment such as anaconda or virtualenvwrapper (if you are using linux), that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just a method to solve the problem, which is `pip install opencv-contrib-python` and now it runs smoothly.