# i am getting error while i run pip install pokitdok?

Tags: python, pip

when i run >pip install pokitdok 
 I got below error 
to run >pip install pokitdok what changes i have to do

```
Exception:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 232, in main
          status = self.run(options, args)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 347, in run
          root=options.root_path,
        File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 543, in install
          requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 667, in uninstall
          paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 126, in remove
          renames(path, new_path)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 316, in renames
          shutil.move(old, new)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 300, in move
          rmtree(src)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree
          onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 250, in rmtree
          os.remove(fullname)
      OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauthlib/__init__.py'
```

Comment: To run -----pip install  pokitdok 
 successfully  what changes i have to do

Comment: Use `sudo pip install poktidok`

Comment: are you trying to install in a virtualenv or globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, you only want to elevate privileges(sudo) if you absolutely have to. One good alternative is to use a Python virtualenv, as described in this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028648/is-it-acceptable-safe-to-run-pip-install-under-sudo).

Of course, if you're just tinkering, it's probably not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install it as `root` user, so use `sudo`:

```
sudo pip install pokitdok
```

Comment: @ramnathreddy you're welcome! you can tell this to community by voting and accepting the answer! ;)