# Global and local python installations, and accidentally running a requirements file outside of virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, requirements.txt

So I was googling an event where pip required sudo privileges,and I came across the following two threads 
[What are the risks of running 'sudo pip'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055859/what-are-the-risks-of-running-sudo-pip)
and 
[Is it acceptable & safe to run pip install under sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028648/is-it-acceptable-safe-to-run-pip-install-under-sudo)

The first thread talks about the security risk of running an unknown .py file with pip (makes sense), but from the second one I almost got the impression that there exists a global and local python installation that you should not mix up.  I guess it makes it sense that you can have a global installation for all users and then maybe an appended path to local packages for each user, but is this true?  (it would also make sense since ubuntu (which I'm using) has dependencies on certain python packages, so having a global root protected python directory would protect these).  However, if this is true, I can't find the two separate directories.  I tried

```
import sys 
print(sys.path)
```

with both sudo and no sudo, and I got the exact same directories.

In any case, I think I'll move to pip virtualenv, but in that case I was wondering, what would happen if I accidentaly forgot to activate the environment and ran an exotic requirements.txt outside?  Wouldn't that corrupt my standard user directory I'm trying so hard to keep clean (if that is so, is that revertible? I'm just thinking, it's only forgetting to type one commando, and then your python installation is messed up.)

Comment: Its fairly simple : Do not forget to activate you virtualenv. Yes, if you run an exotic requirements.txt it could pollute your python installation. One of the first steps before starting a project is to create a separate folder and have a virtualenv there with your required python version.

Comment: *I'm just thinking, it's only forgetting to type one command, and then your python installation is messed up.* Not really. As you are now probably well aware you should not use **sudo** with pip to avoid breaking your *system-wide* Python installation. If you do not use *sudo* with pip then no matter what you install you will not mess up your system. Also, you might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22517157/revisions) information I added  to my answer recently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would indeed advice to always use virtualenv for requirements specific to a certain application. Tools you use as a developer for multiple projects (something like `ipdb`) are fine to install globally on the system.

Note that all pip packages are open source, so you have some assurance that famous pip packages are likely not to have malicious code, but could contain security leaks of course.

To prevent accidentally installing a pip package outside a virtualenv, you can add this to your `.bashrc`:

```
export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true
```

When you then run `pip install something` outside a virtualenv, it will show an error message:

```
Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).
```

If you still want to be able to install pip packages outside a virtualenv, you can add a function in your `.bashrc` like this:

```
syspip() {
    PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="" pip "$@"
}
```

Then you can run `syspip install something` to install something globally on your system.

As for the script you are running:

```
import sys 
print(sys.path)
```

It doesn't matter if you run that with sudo or not, sudo only changes the user privileges you are executing the command with, for this script it doesn't matter.

Comment: *It doesn't matter if you run that with sudo or not, sudo only changes the user privileges you are executing the command with, for this script it doesn't matter.* Not true. Sudo often changes environment including `PATH` which does matter here. See [Does sudo a command temporarily change $PATH to be the root's?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/151310/5355)

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost This is not the same as the bash environment variable `$PATH`, see the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.path

Comment: I'm well aware of what `sys.path` is. However, as it depends on what Python you run it depends on `$PATH` also (if you don't specify exact path to the interpreter).

Answer (score 2):

Running `sudo pip install <package>` will install the package to the system wide set of packages, typically stored somewhere like `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

Running `pip install package` without a virtualenv activated will attempt to install the package to the same place, but because (if your system is configured sanely/correctly) you won't have write access to that folder, the install command will fail.

It's generally better to use distribution packages if you can for global installs if you absolutely have to install globally, as then you get the benefit of automatic updates. As you've worked out however, it's far better to not install packages globally at all, and use virtualenvs