# How can I configure or alias pip to abort if run when not in a virtualenv?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I remember reading that pip can be configured to abort if run when you do not have a virtualenv active. I can't find that article but I'd like to set it up to do this.

I couldn't find a clear option in the `--help` output or from googling.

Comment: also possible duplicate of [Global and local python installations, and accidentally running a requirements file outside of virtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29616164/5205141)

Comment: If you don't have that bad habit of running things as root, `pip` will abort by itself when it realizes it does not have the right to change the global filesystem anyway.

Comment: @spectras If you're on OSX with homebrew running `pip` without sudo has rights to install system packages.

Comment: Oh. You do have a point then. Also that means any user can install any code as a system package. So OSX comes with the bad habit built-in. Great, another good reason not to use it.
Alright, I guess you have to make do with that then. I believe you found the answers you needed in Asagen's link?

Comment: @spectras Homebrew doesn't come with OSX, it's intended for single user systems. On a server you'd probably configure it to work differently.

Comment: Ok, I was wrong then. Thanks for the clarification.