# Can't install python package gensim ubuntu

Tags: python, pip, gensim, ruamel.yaml

I am unable to install any python package through

```
pip install <name>
```

it always throws the error

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-V2srLa/Gensim
Storing debug log for failure in /home/<username>/.pip/pip.log
```

for other packages using `sudo apt-get install python-<name>` used to work but not for gensim

I have tried to insttall/unzip the package and go `python setup.py test
python setup.py install` it throws `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'ruamel.yaml>=0.10.7' distribution was not found and is required by the application`

I have tried to install 'ruamel.yaml>=0.10.7' and it still doesn't work

Any help why this is failing ? and how can I solve it ?

**Update:** moving to root (sudo su) worked for me

Comment: How did you install pip?

Comment: can't remember, it's been a while . most probably: sudo easy_install pip

Answer (score 1):

If you have stumbled upon this question, the best answer is to install gensim and other packages using a virtual environment, not to use sudo or root. See [Is it acceptable and safe to run pip install under sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028648/is-it-acceptable-and-safe-to-run-pip-install-under-sudo), as well as  https://towardsdatascience.com/all-you-need-to-know-about-python-virtual-environments-9b4aae690f9, and https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Answer (score 0):

If you use the system `pip` to install `ruamel.yaml` you don't have enough privileges to write into `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. In that case either use sudo, or install the ruamel.yaml package using:

```
sudo apt-get install python-ruamel.yaml
```

(using `sudo pip install ruamel.yaml` will get you a newer version)

Comment: trying this get's me the errors : 
E: Unable to locate package python-ruamel.yaml
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python-ruamel.yaml'

Comment: @severine Sorry, it looks like it was not yet included in the standard 15.10 repositories. `python-ruamel.yaml` is in 16.04/xenial