# PIP cannot upgrade setuptools

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to upgrade setuptools on CentOS 6 and run into this problem:

```
$ sudo pip install setuptools --no-use-wheel --upgrade
DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
DEPRECATION: --no-use-wheel is deprecated and will be removed in the future.  Please use --no-binary :all: instead.
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-23.0.0.tar.gz (601kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 604kB 578kB/s
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 8.2.1
    Uninstalling setuptools-8.2.1:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-8.2.1
  Running setup.py install for setuptools ... done
Successfully installed setuptools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==8.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.6.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 221, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.6.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 252, in main
    pip_version_check(session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.6.egg/pip/utils/outdated.py", line 102, in pip_version_check
    installed_version = get_installed_version("pip")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.6.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 848, in get_installed_version
    working_set = pkg_resources.WorkingSet()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 619, in __init__
    self.add_entry(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 675, in add_entry
    for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1942, in find_eggs_in_zip
    if metadata.has_metadata('PKG-INFO'):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1463, in has_metadata
    return self.egg_info and self._has(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1824, in _has
    return zip_path in self.zipinfo or zip_path in self._index()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1704, in zipinfo
    return self._zip_manifests.load(self.loader.archive)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1644, in load
    mtime = os.stat(path).st_mtime
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-8.2.1-py2.6.egg'
```

Any suggestions? I tried manually uninstalling and reinstalling with pip and that didn't work. Once setuptools was removed, pip complained that a file was missing and could not proceed with the installation.

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to Python 2.7?

Comment: you did see the `DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported` at the top of the output right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line in the traceback
`File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.6.egg/pip/utils/outdated.py", line 102, in pip_version_check`

shows the error is raised when pip checks for update. As a workaround you can disable this check by passing [`--disable-pip-version-check`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/?highlight=version%20check#cmdoption-disable-pip-version-check) argument to pip.

Also please notice the line
`Successfully installed setuptools`
in the output. Taking above two observations into account I think it's safe to disregard the error.

Also I advise against using *sudo* with pip – see [Is it acceptable & safe to run pip install under sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15028648/95735) Instead use `--user` option or virtualenv.