# Python BeautifulSoup Mac Installation Error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am completely new to all things programming.  As I am working to learn the basics of Python, I have run into a problem that I've been unable to work through by reading and Googling.

I am trying to install BeautifulSoup, and I thought I had done so successfully, but when I try to test whether or not it's installed correctly I get an error.

I am using PyCharm and typed the following into the Python Console:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

And I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
```

I read through a previous thread about a BeautifulSoup install error and one of the things that was mentioned was to check the preferences settings in PyCharm to ensure that it's using the right version of Python . . .

[image: PyCharm Project Interpreter Screenshot]

Anyway, I can't seem to figure out what's wrong, so any insight and help in resolving this issue would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: using virtualenv?

Comment: Describe how you installed BeautifulSoup please?

Comment: @DanielleM. Thank you for getting back to me.  I installed it by downloading (beautifulsoup4-4.5.1) from crummy.com.  Then I unzipped the folder and in terminal typed cd (then the location of the folder contents), then in terminal again I typed sudo python setup.py install.  It seemed to install and then when I tried from bs4 import BeautifulSoup I got the error.

Comment: @lxer I am quite sure that I'm not using a virtual environment, but I honestly wouldn't know.  I simply downloaded Python, then downloaded PyCharm, then started trying to install these modules (not sure what they are called).  Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend going through the command line. GUIs and PyCharm may be nice, but `pip` is the recommended way to get packages installed.

Comment: @cricket_007 When you say command line, I assume you are referring to the terminal that is part of my Mac OSX right?  Do I need to type python in front of the command, or simply pip install beautifulsoup

Comment: @tforbes Yes, the "terminal" application, but commands are ran from the "command line" (they are synonymous). And no `python` unless you are running a script. `pip` is its own command. `install` is a sub-command, then `beautifulsoup` is the argument to install

Comment: @cricket_007 got it and thank you for that clarification.  I tried easy_install beautifulsoup4 through the command line.  I am not sure if it worked, but I didn't seem to get an error.

Answer (score -2):

You can use pip to install beautifulsoup on mac, by typing in the following command in Terminal:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

You might be facing some permission problems if you are running the OS X preinstalled python as interpreter. I would suggest installing python with Homebrew if that's the case.

Comment: Thank you.  When you say I might be facing permission problems, does the sudo command in front of what you typed help with that?

Comment: @tforbes [Use a virtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15028735/2308683)

Comment: I typed the command as you had it and I received an error.  I tried to copy and paste the error into a comment but it was too long.  Is there a way for me to copy and paste code into these replies?

Comment: Try:  easy_install beautifulsoup4

Comment: @CasperTN thank you, I typed that in using regular Mac terminal (not PyCharm).  I don't know if it worked or not, but it said, Processing dependencies for beautifulsoup4
Finished processing dependencies for beautifulsoup4 .  Is there a way for me to test if it worked?

Comment: @cricket_007 Do I need to uninstall or delete what has already been done in order to setup a virtual environment?

Comment: @tforbes You may need to install `virtualenv`, but no clean up is necessary.

Comment: The easiest way to check if its installed and in python path, open a terminal, run python and type

   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

if there is no error message then its installed and on python modules path

Comment: @CasperTN I ran from bs4 import BeautifulSoup.  I don't get any errors when I do it from terminal, I do get errors when I do it within PyCharm Python Console.  Is that normal, and can I assume that the BeautifulSoup question has been successfully resolved?

Comment: Try this:  pip install bs4

Comment: And then when you import: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Comment: Try to restart Pycharm to let it update its libraries

Comment: @CasperTN I received -- Successfully installed bs4-0.0.1.  When I restart Pycharm, will it update it's libraries on its own, or is it something that I need to do specifically?

Comment: Wow.  Thank you all for your help.  This seems to be working perfectly fine now.  I am so very appreciative.  How do I mark that this question was successfully resolved?

Comment: First up vote it by clicking the up arrow and then click the green mark.