# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.md'

Tags: python, pip, adobe-analytics

When I try to install omniture using pip I receive the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.md'
```

I am basically trying to connect to the Adobe Analytics API.
Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more context for your question. [How to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good resource. As such, all we can tell is that the file README.md doesn't exist where you're trying to access it.

Comment: On installing through git link it throws error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/omniture': Permission denied and if you go to setup.py file you will find long_description=open('README.md').read() and README.md is available there –

Answer (score 7, accepted):

omniture module on PyPi is missing the README.md file, hence the IOError you get.

If you want to install this module, install it through its github repo as below:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/stdbrouw/python-omniture.git
```

For more information check [its GitHub link](https://github.com/dancingcactus/python-omniture)

Comment: On installing through git link it throws error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/omniture': Permission denied  and if you go to setup.py file you will find long_description=open('README.md').read() and README.md is available there

Comment: It is because you do not have permissions on your system to create this directory. If you are on Linux call it as sudo:  `sudo pip install git+git://github.com/stdbrouw/python-omniture.git`. In Windows execute it as Admin.

Comment: I realize this is a 2 year old comment, but I feel it should be said here for anyone who runs across this that running pip as sudo is generally a very bad idea. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028648/is-it-acceptable-and-safe-to-run-pip-install-under-sudo).

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem once with a `README.adoc`, and I solved it by adding `README.adoc` to the `MANIFEST.in` file and republishing my package.