# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13]

Tags: python, macos, pip

In my MacOS Mojave terminal I wanted to install a python package with pip. At the end it says:

```
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

So I wanted to update pip with the given command but I got an error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-18.0-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/PKG-INFO'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I don't really understand what to do now. **Also I realized it says Python 2.7 in the error message but I have and want to use only python 3.**

Comment: Did you read the: "Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions."?

Comment: I just tried it you are right! I thought it would CHECK the permissions and not GIVE permissions. Thank you!

Comment: To install packages for python3 you need to use pip3 To upgrade pip just run as sudo if you run into permission errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Could+not+install+packages+due+to+an+EnvironmentError%3A+Errno+13+Permission+denied%3A+%2FLibrary%2FPython%2F2.7%2Fsite-packages%2F

Answer (score 367, accepted):

If you want to use **python3+** to install the packages you need to use `pip3 install package_name`

And to solve the **errno 13** you have to add `--user` at the end

```
pip3 install package_name --user
```

---

**EDIT:**

For any project in Python it's **highly recommended** to work on a [**Virtual environment**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-virtual-environment/), which is a tool that helps to keep dependencies required by different projects separate by creating isolated Python virtual environments for them.

In order to create one with **python3+** you have to use the following command:

```
virtualenv enviroment_name -p python3
```

And then you work on it just by **activating** it:

```
source enviroment_name/bin/activate
```

Once the virtual environment is activated, the name of your virtual environment will appear on the left side of the terminal. This will let you know that the virtual environment is currently active.
Now you can install dependencies related to the project in this virtual environment by just using `pip`.

```
pip install package_name
```

Comment: I did this but I am still having a trouble. I installed flask but it still cannot be found within my venv. What can I do?

Comment: Try virtualenv -p python3.8 enviroment_name
Usage: virtualenv [OPTIONS] DEST_DIR

Comment: @Leonard I'm having this same issue, it's not installing in the venv. It's extremely frustrating, how did you fix it?

Comment: @GonzaloGarcia nope just regular python. I did not suspect such a simple task would cause such a significant issue

Comment: @Amon hi there, i asked this when i was a total noob and had a messed up python environment, when i didnt know i should not use anaconda and pip together. I basically reset all python environment, did clean new fresh install and havent faced much issue ever since.

Comment: I was having some of the same issues.  What worked for me was to first create a virtualenv,   activate the venv, then upgrade pip, then install whatever you need without interfering with the system settings.

Comment: @TimothyLombard Why not running the upgrade on the "system python" before creating the venv? The things that need to be updated have to be updated in any venv, so why not doing that already in the system install? I thought the venv is only put on top of the system install unless you tell it to have a chosen python version using `-p python3.10` when your system install is Python `3.8`?

Answer (score 54):

I changed the rights of the venv that I was working in since the permissions were missing in the virtual environment subfolders.

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx testenv
```

Then I could install an automatically recommended package from within codium.

Mind that this loops through the rights of *all* folders and files in your venv. If you work in a git repository that should keep most of its file rights so that you do not spam the git log, if you have write-protected database folders, or anything else the like, you should try picking only the folders that need a change, likely the built-in modules. Check the dependencies of the package you want to install inside the code or on the net. This is not a quick workaround anymore.

Comment: Only this solution worked. None of the other ones worked. Thank you.

Comment: This answer helped me in WSL 2.

Comment: This is bad if you're working in repo, as now all files get modified.

Comment: @dval I put that at the end of the answer.

Comment: This is the solution, you just need to give the virtual environment folder permissions.

Answer (score 37):

Regarding the permissions command, try using sudo in front of your terminal command:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

Sudo allows you to run the command with the privileges of the superuser and will install the package for the global, system-wide Python installation. Ideally, you should create a virtual environment for the project you are working on. Have a look at [this](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/26/python-virtual-env/)

Regarding the python Try running pip as an executable like this:

```
python3.6 -m pip install <package>
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but running this kind of commands with root permissions usually is not the best idea: once you use sudo the user will change from "you" to "root", and that could lead to unwanted results. For example, libraries could be installed in /home/root instead of /home/yourusername. Also, files will be created in association with the root user/group. Sudo is needed only when the command should save files in system folders like /usr/local/bin ! ;)

Comment: Yes, that's true. I've added a comment on that

Answer (score 13):

To see if it's actually a problem with permissions run the following to install a package named `xxx`.

```
pip install --user xxx
```

for eg: to install package `bcrypt` run,

```
pip install --user bcrypt
```

Comment: This solved my life, but I had to include `-Iv` to overwrite what has been installed, `pip install -Iv --user xxx==x.y.z`, eg: `pip install -Iv --user pandas==1.3.5`

Answer (score 11):

I was making the same mistakes then I realized that I have created my virtual environment as root user. It was write protected, so please check whether your virtual environment is write protected. make a new venv and try again

Comment: Thats right check this tutorial and follow exactly (without changes) it works : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 10):

The answer is in the error message.  In the past you or a process did a `sudo pip` and that caused some of the directories under `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/...` to have permissions higher than current user.

Then you did a `pip install whatever` which modifies a directory you don't have write access to.

So to fix it, visit the `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/...` find the directory with the root or elevated permissions and either `rm -rf yourpackages` then reinstall the packages with your user, or just force ownership there to the user to whom ought to have access using `chown -R ...` or `chmod -R ...`

Comment: simple and working.
use $whoami to know which user you are currently
then $sudo chown username /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ 
then pip install whatever... You might have to use chown recursively

Comment: Classic python-unix permission fight: `pip install blah` in an unix privileged directory assimilates to the higher, and unix puts it out of reach, then pip comes around for a second pass and says: "I can't change these directories or files".  Here the python newbie gets to google search: "linux permission system".

Comment: Just came to say that this was the exact answer I needed. I had some cruft leftover from getting Python to run on Apple Silicon when it was first released and it's pained me all the way until now. Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem while installing `numpy` with `pip install numpy`.

Then I tried

`sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip`

`sudo -H pip3 install numpy`

It worked well for me.

**Explanation  :** 
The `-H` (HOME) option with `sudo` sets the HOME environment variable to the home directory of the target user (root by default). By default, sudo does not modify HOME.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error when I was trying to install a package (flask-classful).
I made the mistake of installing anaconda as root. I changed the ownership of the installed anaconda folder and I could install the package successfully.

Use the command `chown` with option `-R` to recursively change ownership of the installed anaconda folder like so:

`chown -R owner:group /path/to/anaconda`

Here owner is your username and group is the group name.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
 python3 -m venv env
 source ./env/bin/activate
 python -m pip install package
```

(From Github: https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/236 )

Answer (score 4):

I was running `python3 -m pip install xxx`

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/3.8'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

`/Library/Python/3.8` Indicates that `python3` I'm using is the system wide python, and hence permission issues. Solutions involving `--user` flags and virtual envs are all solving this issue.

For me, using brew the most convenient:

```
brew install python@3.8
brew link python@3.8
which python3
```

After which `python3 -m pip install xxx` succeed without problems. Note that sudo should not be used.

The principle is the same: you are starting a new environment that is less privileged. This implies all the packages you need from the old environment need to be installed again in this new environment.

I guess use the `--user` flag if you don't want to reinstall everything.

Answer (score 2):

For MacOs & Unix

Just by adding sudo to command will work, as it would run it as a superuser.

`sudo pip install --upgrade pip`

It is advised that you should not directly do it though - please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028648/is-it-acceptable-and-safe-to-run-pip-install-under-sudo)

Comment: This isn't helpful to Windows users at all, and this error is more common with Windows users due to Windows operating permissions. Also, commands should be enclosed in code blocks, when they're not it makes it hard to read

Answer (score 1):

try this command line below for **MacOS** to check user's permission.

```
$ sudo python -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

I have anaconda installed for Python 3. I also have Python2 in my mac.

```
python --version
```

gives me

> Python 3.7.3

```
python2.7 --version
```

gives me

> Python 2.7.10

I wanted to install pyspark package in python2, given that it was already installed in python3.

```
python2.7 -m pip install pyspark
```

gives me an error

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13]
>   Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyspark'
>   Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

The below command solved it. Thank god I didn't have to do any config changes.

```
python2.7 -m pip install pyspark --user
```

> Collecting pyspark Requirement already satisfied: py4j==0.10.7 in
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pyspark) (0.10.7) Installing
>   collected packages: pyspark Successfully installed pyspark-2.4.4 You
>   are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.3.1 is available. You
>   should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Answer (score 1):

I already tried all suggestion posted in here, yet I'm still getting the errno 13,

I'm using Windows and my python version is 3.7.3

After 5 hours of trying to solve it, this step worked for me:

I try to open the command prompt by **run as administrator**

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue, got solved with

```
sudo chown -R myuser /Users/myuser/Library/Python/
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, I tried many different command lines, this one worked for me:

Try:

```
    conda install py-xgboost
```

That's what I got:

```
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/simplonco/anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - py-xgboost


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    _py-xgboost-mutex-2.0      |            cpu_0           9 KB
    ca-certificates-2019.1.23  |                0         126 KB
    certifi-2018.11.29         |           py37_0         146 KB
    conda-4.6.2                |           py37_0         1.7 MB
    libxgboost-0.80            |       he6710b0_0         3.7 MB
    mkl-2019.1                 |              144       204.6 MB
    mkl_fft-1.0.10             |   py37ha843d7b_0         169 KB
    mkl_random-1.0.2           |   py37hd81dba3_0         405 KB
    numpy-1.15.4               |   py37h7e9f1db_0          47 KB
    numpy-base-1.15.4          |   py37hde5b4d6_0         4.2 MB
    py-xgboost-0.80            |   py37he6710b0_0         1.7 MB
    scikit-learn-0.20.2        |   py37hd81dba3_0         5.7 MB
    scipy-1.2.0                |   py37h7c811a0_0        17.7 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       240.0 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  _py-xgboost-mutex  pkgs/main/linux-64::_py-xgboost-mutex-2.0-cpu_0
  libxgboost         pkgs/main/linux-64::libxgboost-0.80-he6710b0_0
  py-xgboost         pkgs/main/linux-64::py-xgboost-0.80-py37he6710b0_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  ca-certificates     anaconda::ca-certificates-2018.12.5-0 --> pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2019.1.23-0
  mkl                                            2019.0-118 --> 2019.1-144
  mkl_fft                              1.0.4-py37h4414c95_1 --> 1.0.10-py37ha843d7b_0
  mkl_random                           1.0.1-py37h4414c95_1 --> 1.0.2-py37hd81dba3_0
  numpy                               1.15.1-py37h1d66e8a_0 --> 1.15.4-py37h7e9f1db_0
  numpy-base                          1.15.1-py37h81de0dd_0 --> 1.15.4-py37hde5b4d6_0
  scikit-learn                        0.19.2-py37h4989274_0 --> 0.20.2-py37hd81dba3_0
  scipy                                1.1.0-py37hfa4b5c9_1 --> 1.2.0-py37h7c811a0_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  certifi                                          anaconda --> pkgs/main
  conda                                            anaconda --> pkgs/main
  openssl                anaconda::openssl-1.1.1-h7b6447c_0 --> pkgs/main::openssl-1.1.1a-h7b6447c_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
libxgboost-0.80      | 3.7 MB    | ##################################### | 100% 
mkl_random-1.0.2     | 405 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
certifi-2018.11.29   | 146 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
ca-certificates-2019 | 126 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
conda-4.6.2          | 1.7 MB    | ##################################### | 100% 
mkl-2019.1           | 204.6 MB  | ##################################### | 100% 
mkl_fft-1.0.10       | 169 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
numpy-1.15.4         | 47 KB     | ##################################### | 100% 
scipy-1.2.0          | 17.7 MB   | ##################################### | 100% 
scikit-learn-0.20.2  | 5.7 MB    | ##################################### | 100% 
py-xgboost-0.80      | 1.7 MB    | ##################################### | 100% 
_py-xgboost-mutex-2. | 9 KB      | ##################################### | 100% 
numpy-base-1.15.4    | 4.2 MB    | ##################################### | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar trouble in a venv on a mounted NTFS partition on linux with all the right permissions.
Making sure pip ran with **--ignore-installed** solved it, i.e.:

`python -m pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed`

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, there is no `3.7` directory or the directory `3.7` is owned by `root`. So, I removed that directory, create a new directory by current user, and move it there. Then installation finishes without error.

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Python/3.7
mkdir 3.7
sudo mv 3.7 /Library/Python
ll /Library/Python/
pip3 install numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

This also happens to me when I try to install the `opencv-python` package:

[image: installation attempt]

I can fix it with command line

```
python3 -m pip install {name of package} --user
```

When I try to install the said package, the command becomes:

```
python3 -m pip install opencv-python --user
```

Resulting in this:

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes once you run into this error you might have to remove and recreate the virtual environment as pip will not work. The reason is that while you were trying to upgrade pip, the old version is removed with unsuccessful installation of the new one due to access permissions.
Then @Gonzalo Garcia's answer is applicable.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34459824)

Answer (score 0):

sudo chown -R root:root /home/root/my_repo/venv

Answer (score -14):

just `sudo pip install packagename`

Comment: giving a command that elevates to superuser without any explanation about the consequences is really bad advice. Especially so if you don't understand it yourself.