# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: How I solve it?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views

When I run:

```
pip install djangorestframework
```

I got this error message:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/asgiref'
>   Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: Hello, this is a pretty common error in the usage of pip, I guess.

Use the suggested `--user` to install the package in your home directory or use a [virtualenv](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/venv.html).

Comment: If you are already using an virtual env on ubuntu and if you get this error,then navigate to your virtual env folder.If you see a lock symbol 
Then you don't have the appropriate permission as a user to pip install inside this.Hence change the permission of the venv folder using this command:

    sudo chown -R $USER path/to/venv

Now switch to the venv and install your package.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just add 'sudo' and it should work: sudo pip install djangorestframework

It missing permission to open the asgiref file. Prob a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52949531/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-13/53916143)

Comment: You should carefully advice to use `sudo` because of security reasons. It's easy to make a mistake a accidentally install something else then you expect and have much bigger problems.

Comment: I advise against installing package as root (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055859/what-are-the-risks-of-running-sudo-pip). A better way should be `pip install --user djangorestframework`.

Answer (score 1):

You simply have not enought permissions to install library to user dir.
Consider using [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) instead of installing all modules in your local Python repository.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo pip install djangorestframework` . 
`sudo` basically makes you a superuser with privileges to install new packages, you can read about it [here](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.14/sudo.man.html) in detail