# Unable to install python twint package under MacOS Catalina

Tags: python, macos, installation, macos-catalina, twint

I want to install pip3 install twint but I get the error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/3.8'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

what command do i need to type to install it under my user option?
would it be `python -m pip3 install twint`?

Comment: run as administrator, if you are on a Mac, prefix by sudo

Comment: Not clear how you installed python3, but /Library requires elevated permission

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: \[Errno 13\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52949531/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-13)

Comment: `sudo` is the solution, insofar as it allows you to do something you probably should not be doing. If any *system* tools needed `twint`, it would come with the system or be pushed as an update from Apple. Don't modify the *system* installation because *you* need a particular module.

Comment: I added the tags [tag:macos], [tag:macos-catalina], [tag:installation]. For most MacOS issues, look also at solutions for previous releases.

Comment: @chepner: sudo is generally **not** the solution, it only pushes the original problem (installing Python as administrator,) further around.

Comment: Did you install Python while logged in as administrator (e.g. with Anaconda)? That's generally a bad idea (both on Windows and MacOS) and causes permissions issues like this when installing packages.

Comment: @smci That's why I said "don't modify the system installation".

Comment: @chepner: no that's different again. I don't believe the OP is referring to the system installation which on MacOS is under `/usr/bin/python` and also it doesn't come with `pip` installed, so not likely what they're asking about. I'm talking about third-party Python installs (`/usr/local/bin/python`, Homebrew path, Anaconda: `/opt/your_path_goes_here/python`, etc.) It is possible to install them as administrator, and that's generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

as suggested by pip, use `--user`: `python3 -m pip install --user twint`

it will install your package in your home (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs)

as a better alternative, you can look into [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing this using the Anaconda Navigator cmd. The installation did not work in Jupyter Notebook, but it did work in Anaconda Navigator cmd.