# can't install any package in virtual environment due to SOCKS dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-venv

### Issue:

I create virtual environment either using venv:

```
python -m venv <venv-name>
```

or using conda:

```
conda create -n <venv-name>
```

when I activate it and try to install any python package **using pip/ pip3**, I see this error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.
```

while installing packages outside of the venv is OK.

### Info:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- conda is my default package manager
- I connect via tor to download packages

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: \[Errno 13\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52949531/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-13)

Comment: @zvone No it doesn't. The error is different if you check. Mine is due to SOCKS dependencies, not Permission.

Comment: I got this error, though not just in the virtual env, also in the system. I closed my shell and opened a new one. It worked. I guess you tried this?