# Pip doesn't require root user to install but requires root user to upgrade

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm confused by the intended pip usage. Pip comes installed with Python, which is great, but I get the following warnings when new versions come out:

```
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.1; however, version 21.1.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I follow the instructions to install it using the command they gave. But then it uninstalls my existing pip and is not able to install the new version.

```
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 21.1.1
    Uninstalling pip-21.1.1:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Cannot move the non-empty directory '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-21.1.1.dist-info/': Lacking write permission to '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-21.1.1.dist-info/'.
```

The `pip` command is now unrecognized, and the official [documentation](http://documentation) for upgrading pip suggests running:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

which gives the same permission error.

I Google this error, and found that the community highly advises to not sudo from these questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52949531/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-13) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-failing-with-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied-on-directory)). They also advised `pip3 install --upgrade pip --user` which also gave the same error. The common consensus is to only install pip packages inside virtual environments, but I'm hesitant to have pip completely uninstalled.

So I got pip to install using `sudo`, but it's unclear whether I've inadvertently affected (or will affect future) system-wide installations, or how I'd check for these.

I don't understand why installing `pip` inside `/usr/local/` requires `sudo`, and whether I should only be using pip exclusively inside virtual environments and never outside it

Comment: Because the `/usr/local` folder is owned by `root`.  You aren't allowed to change it.  As a rule, I tend to install most packages with `sudo`, just so they're available everywhere.

Comment: In general, /usr/local is a root owned area. It is better to keep permissions strict because you install a lot less frequently than you run. If you are using a system-wide python that all users can use, then it makes sense not to allow users to install whatever package they want. Any user can install packages / libraries locally with user. All that being said, it is fine to upgrade pip with sudo.

Comment: What installed `pip` under `/usr/local/opt` in the first place? That's the only thing that should be upgrading `pip`. If you want a more up-to-date version without touching `/usr/local/opt`, create a virtual environment first.

Comment: `pip` is not part of the standard Python distribution; it's a 3rd-party tool that some particular distribution installed *along with* Python.

Comment: Did the Python you're using come with your distro? In particular is `pip` a package in your package manager? If so, upgrade `pip` using the package manager. (The upgrade might not be available right away through that channel, though. Alternatively, uninstall that and install `pip` using `python -m ensurepip`

Answer (score 0):

`pip` can be installed with `sudo`, into a folder that you don't have permissions to write to. However, it can install packages *outside* of that folder (and thus, into a folder you have write permissions). However, it is recommended that you don't install `pip` into a root folder, and instead install it into your home directory.

Answer (score -1):

The command to install pip as root is

```
sudo apt-get install pip
```

It should then prompt you for your password. I recommend using sudo whenever you install something.