# I upgraded pyOpenSSL but it is still 0.13.1 version. Unable to upgrade to 18.0.0

Tags: scrapy, pip, web-crawler

I am trying to get pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 but it doesn't work. Here are my commands:

```
sudo pip install pyOpenSSL==18.0.0
```

I get this:

```
The directory '/Users/mac/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/mac/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: pyOpenSSL==18.0.0 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (18.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pyOpenSSL==18.0.0) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.2.1 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyOpenSSL==18.0.0) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL==18.0.0) (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version < "3" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL==18.0.0) (1.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.7 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL==18.0.0) (1.11.5)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL==18.0.0) (0.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipaddress; python_version < "3" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL==18.0.0) (1.0.22)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.7->cryptography>=2.2.1->pyOpenSSL==18.0.0) (2.19)
```

Looks like pyOpenSSL is already installed. But then I check:

```
pip list
```

And I get:

```
pyOpenSSL    0.13.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sudo` command might be making pip install that version of `pyopenssl` to the site-packages of the `root` user. Simply running `pip install pyOpenSSL==18.0.0` (outside of a virtual environment) should install it in the site-packages of the current user.

As an aside, you should consider using virtual environments for better dependency management of your python project. For that, please reference {[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15028735/1692706)}.

Comment: Indeed, this is the best practice. I use it now. Thank you!