# How to fix pip error when installing requests

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I was trying to use the Terminal on Ubuntu 16.04 to install Requests for API calls in Python and had this error. How would I go about fixing it?

I have already tried creating a virtualenv to install it only there but it did not work either.

I typed in "pip install requests"

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main status = self.run(options, args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run prefix=options.prefix_path,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 726, in install requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 746, in uninstall paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove renames(path, new_path)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames shutil.move(old, new)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 300, in move
    rmtree(src)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 250, in rmtree
    os.remove(fullname)

OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/idna/codec.pyc'
```

Comment: Look at your last line, `Permission denied`, you might have messed up with folder permissions.

Comment: Like @AlexITC said, you have to check your folder pemissions.

Comment: How would I check my folder permissions?

Comment: You need to be root to install packages to */usr/lib*. Using a virtualenv should have worked. How did you create your virtualenv?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing using the `sudo` keyword to give yourself privilege evaluations. The following should work as long as you know your credentials.

```
sudo pip install requests
```

Comment: It's not recommended to be doing `sudo pip install`, using a virtualenv would have been better. See [Is it acceptable and safe to run pip install under sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028648/is-it-acceptable-and-safe-to-run-pip-install-under-sudo)

Answer (score 0):

When you are opening the command prompt, make sure you `open it as administrator`. You can do this by: (assuming you are on windows)

1: Clicking the windows key

2: Typing in `Command Prompt`

3: **Right Clicking** the first option and choosing `Run as Administrator`

4: Clicking yes in the box that should appear.

After all of that, you should be able to use `pip install Requests` and install it. If that doesn't work, you can use this command instead (still in administrator mode):

`python -m easy_install Requests`
or
`python -m pip install Requests`

Comment: You can also use the command `python -m pip install Requests`.

Comment: The OP is on Ubuntu, as indicated by "_I was trying to use the Terminal on Ubuntu 16.04_" and the fact that all paths start with */usr/lib*. There is no "Run as Administrator" on Ubuntu.

Comment: Oh, shoot. Thanks for pointing that out to me. In that case, he can use the two commands I put in the last line