# pip install trains fails

Tags: python, pip, trains, clearml

upon running `pip install trains` in my virtual env

I am getting

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/epdadmin/noam/code/venv_linux/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-owzh8lnl/retrying/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-owzh8lnl/retrying/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-lxz5t8pu/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/epdadmin/noam/code/venv_linux/include/site/python3.8/retrying
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-owzh8lnl/retrying/
    Complete output (10 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    copying retrying.py -> build/lib
    running install_lib
    copying build/lib/retrying.py -> /home/epdadmin/noam/code/venv_linux/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    byte-compiling /home/epdadmin/noam/code/venv_linux/lib/python3.8/site-packages/retrying.py to retrying.cpython-38.pyc
    error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/epdadmin/noam/code/venv_linux/lib/python3.8/site-packages/__pycache__/retrying.cpython-38.pyc.139678407381360'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/epdadmin/noam/code/venv_linux/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-owzh8lnl/retrying/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-owzh8lnl/retrying/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-lxz5t8pu/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/epdadmin/noam/code/venv_linux/include/site/python3.8/retrying Check the logs for full command output.
```

I know that [I am not supposed to run under sudo when using a venv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028648/is-it-acceptable-and-safe-to-run-pip-install-under-sudo), so I don't really understand the problem

running for example `pip install pandas` does work.

Python 3.8

How to install trains?

---

EDIT:

running `pip install trains --user` or `pip install --user trains` gives

```
ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.
```

Comment: Looks like you've already borked your venv by running commands as root while having venv activated. Restore the ownership: run `id -un` to get the name, `id -gn` to get the group, then `sudo chown -R name:grp /home/epdadmin/noam/code/venv_linux/`, substituting `name` and `grp` with values you've obtained earlier. Then retry `pip install trains`

Comment: `pip install pandas` probably only works because you already have `pandas` installed, so `pip` doesn't do anything. Try e.g. `pip install pandas --force-reinstall`, most probably it will also fail.

Comment: @hoefling force reinstall did not fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a permissions problem for the venv.
Another problem was trains required some packages that were not yet available with wheels on Python3.8, so I had to downgrade Python to 3.7

That venv was created using Pycharm, and for some reason it was created with low permissions.

There was probably a way to elevate its permissions, but instead I just deleted it and created another one using command line by

```
python -m virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.7 venv
```

And now `pip install trains` worked.

Very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Create a virtual environment and install your packages inside it (preferred)
2. Install your packages inside your user home directory by passing --user flag

   `pip install --user`

Comment: Thanks. 1. I am already in a virtual environment, will edit now (although it is in the logs). 2. I have tried, and getting `ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.`

Comment: @Gulzar can you uninstall `retrying` package and re-try?

Comment: How? I will type the commands you tell me to. I am a long time Windows user, I just need to get my Python to work on a remote linux machine, so don't really know linux commands out of my head

Comment: @Martin.B same error when trying to `pip install retrying` after uninstalling. How do I solve this permission issue? it only happens on some installations, and not others.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with installing matplotlib in Ubuntu 18.

Running these lines worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
apt-get install build-essential
```

As found on [setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053982/setup-script-exited-with-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-with-exit)