# pip3 SSL Error while installing new package

Tags: python, shell, kali-linux

I am using Kali Linux, and I am trying to install some requirements of one packet for test purposes, but I keep getting the below error. I have tried many solutions but they are all not working and the error still persists

```
# pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

or

```
pip3 install name_of_package-py
```

[image: error I am getting - picture]

Comment: What python version are you running?

Comment: Please post errors as text, not as a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the only command you would need is:

```
pip install name_of_package
```

if it doesn't work you could try:

```
sudo pip install name_of_package
```

sudo should work, but you have to be careful regarding the package because with sudo you could end up installing a package with some malware in it. Therefore be certain of the reliability of the package.

also depending on the version you are using could be pip or pip3

Comment: Thank you for your support, it works with me after I have deleted #3 from PIP,

Comment: `sudo` also force-installs the package system-wide, in the same python environment used by your OS/system, which can break things. We should stop recommending `sudo pip`. Either use `pip install --user` or a virtual environment. See [Is it acceptable and safe to run pip install under sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15028648/2745495)