# Could not install Packages Due to an EnviromentError - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

when I try to install **webdrivermanager** for selenium library and python but there is an error about the permissions. I am using Macbook Air M1 Chip

I tried these commands:

**pip3 install webdrivermanager**

**pip3 install webdriver_manager**

**pip3 install webdriver-manager**

[image]

Comment: Did you follow the error message's advice and install using the `--user` flag?

Comment: Friendly reminder _not_ to use `sudo` to "fix" pip permission errors. See [Is it acceptable and safe to run pip install under sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15028648/11082165) and [What are the risks of running 'sudo pip'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21055859/11082165)