# Python IDLE wont' start (Mac) - Problems from a Python/Unix newbie

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Months ago, I installed `Python 2.7` on my MacBook Pro (OS 10.8.5) and was using IDLE to run programs for classes I was taking on Udacity. One morning IDLE would no longer start, it would just bounce around on the dock and then close. I was eventually able to get things working again by installing Python 3.3 and using that IDLE.

A few days ago, I tried to get 2.7 working again by uninstalling all versions of Python and reinstalling using Macports. (To uninstall, I simply deleted the Python folders in my application folder, the Python.framework file in /Library/Frameworks and some symlinks in  /usr/local/bin.  Got the idea from another post here: [How to uninstall Python 2.7 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4))

Now no version of Python is working for me. When I try to start IDLE, I get the following error message in the Console:

```
2/7/14 10:28:02.556 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[151]: ([0x0-0xc80c8].org.python.IDLE[819]) Exited with code: 1
```

The Python in the terminal still works, by the way. I also tried installing another IDE, PyCharm, but that doesn't work either (I get a message saying `No Python interpreter selected`)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a MacPorts Python, you will need to install the corresponding `py*-tkinter` port to use any Tkinter-based Python app, including `IDLE`.  Try:

```
sudo port install py27-tkinter
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Ed but I'm afraid that didn't work. I got the same error and IDLE wouldn't start.  (Truth be told, I don't understand why installing Python is so complicated or what programs like Macports do exactly)  For the time being, I can't help but think that I screwed things up by trying to install Python with multiple packages - PIP, Homebrew, Macports... I was clicking and downloading and installing like a madman!  Is there some way to raze the digital ground, erase all evidence of these installs, and restart carefully from scratch?

Comment: Your question (and my answer) is really not on-topic for Stackoverflow. It would be better suited to Ask Different (http://apple.stackexchange.com) or Super User (http://superuser.com). Nevertheless, the answer is that installing Python doesn't need to be complicated.  MacPorts, Homebrew, and python.org binary installers can all install Python (and in the case, of the first two, many other open source packages). The key is to pick one and stick with it.  If you just need the latest Pythons, use python.org installers. If you will also need 3rd-party libs, use MacPorts or Homebrew.

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/367434/how-do-you-remove-macports-and-all-the-packages-it-has-installed

Comment: I had the exact same problem, and installing py27-tkinter worked perfectly.  Thanks!