# Duplicate Python Installations

Tags: python, installation

I had a manual installed python 2.7.5 version.

And since I need to use some statistical packages, I found anaconda to be more convenient, and installed anaconda, which include python 2.7.6

I have the following questions:

> 1. do I essentially need to remove/uninstall the previous manually installed version to avoid potential dependency problems?

Was trying to remove, but not successful so far, any hints? I followed suggestions on this board: [How to uninstall Python 2.7 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4), but find no luck yet.

> 2. will the previously downloaded/installed packages still work in anaconda, e.g., I launched NLTK in anaconda's python, and the previously downloaded corpuses are still there installed?

Comment: How did you manually install the other versions of python? Did you use a packing manager like `brew`

Answer (score 1):

You should use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/). Virtualenv allows you to create a virtual python environment for each project, so you can have different libraries for different projects, this includes different python versions.

Comment: This answer is a bit shy tho. You could add how to install `pip` and then install `virtualenv` and finally show a small rollout of `virtualenv` itself. +1 tho