# Python installation issue? AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MINYEAR'

Tags: python

Python installation seems to have gone wrong on my mac. I get the above error no matter what modules I try to use. For example simple code as below gives me the above error:

```
import datetime
print(datetime.MINYEAR)
```

The same thing works fine when I try from interactive shell.

What's going wrong?

I have installed python3.4. How can I check if my installation is correct?

I tried uninstalling ([How to uninstall Python 2.7 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4)) and installing it again. But no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Make your the file you're coding in isn't called `datetime.py`. Rename it to `mydatetime.py` and it should work.

If your file is called `datetime.py`, then

```
import datetime
```

attempts to import your own file as a module, and of course your file probably doesn't have `MINYEAR` as an attribute.

Edit: Make sure to also remove any files in your current working directory named `datetime.py` or `datetime.pyc`

As DSM pointed out, you can use `print(datetime.__file__)` to print where you are importing `datetime` module from. On my system, you can clearly see it's importing from a system library (`.so` file):

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Comment: No luck. It was time.py earlier, I changed to something else but still same error.

Comment: Make sure there's no file in your current folder named `datetime.py` or `datetime.pyc`

Comment: You can check which `datetime` it is by `print(datetime.__file__)` after it's been imported.