# Completely remove Python from Yosemite machine

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm having issues with Python on my 2013 MacBook Air. It seems to be mostly related to pathing, looking for libs in the wrong location based on where the calling lib was installed. I'd like to remove Python from my system and start fresh.

The specific reason I'm asking is due to a virtualenv problem. I created an env with the no-site-packages flag, but when I start my app with foreman, I get an error telling me that Flask isn't available  yet when I open a python shell and "import flask", it works fine.

I don't really care which version of Python, or where it's installed as long as everything is consistent. Could I get advisement on how to proceed?

To be clear, I don't think this is a Yosemite issue, just mentioning it as a potential variable.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4) ?

Comment: I didn't, but neither of those initial directories exist on my Mac.