# Python on Yosemite

Tags: python, upgrade, osx-yosemite

Just got a new Mac with Yosemite. Ran the Migration Assistant to move files over from older machine. Now I find myself with an "old" (2.7.2) version of Python that doesn't work on Yosemite (crash at second line of interactive command line).

Either Apple ships Yosemite with a really old version of Python, or MA decided to overwrite the one that was there with an older one from my old machine?

Hoping that there is a way to solve this that doesn't involve multiple manual steps... but I haven't found an obvious way. Any Pythonistas out there that have a magic bullet for me?

Also - is this the right forum for this question or should I move it to Ask Different (apple.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: When I get a new mac, the first thing I do is go to activestate.com and download ActivePython. It's a simple install that gives you python and pip.

Comment: As of Python 2.7.9 and Python 3.4.x, the python.org installers for OS X include pip as well.

Comment: Floris, you undoubtedly had another version of Python installed, independent of the Apple-supplied system Pythons, which was migrated.  If you used python.org installers, that Python would be in `/Library/Frameworks`. If you use a third-party package manager like MacPorts or Homebrew it is likely somewhere else. You can use `type python` to find out where you are picking up Python from and then either upgrade it or remove it.  Do not try to remove the Apple Pythons in `/System/Library/Frameworks`.  With Yosemite, Apple ships 2.7.6.

Comment: @NedDeily Indeed, I had 2.7.2 on the (very) old machine. I found version 2.7.6 where you said it would be. Would the simplest thing be to remove the "other" python (apparently imported by MA) - what would be the right way to ensure that typing `python` at the command line gets me back to the right place? In other words - how do I uninstall 2.7.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You undoubtedly had another version of Python installed, independent of the Apple-supplied system Pythons, which was migrated. If you used python.org installers, that Python would be in `/Library/Frameworks`. If you use a third-party package manager, like MacPorts or Homebrew, it is likely somewhere else. You can use `type python` to find out where you are picking up Python from and then either upgrade it or remove it. Do not try to remove the Apple Pythons in `/System/Library/Frameworks`. With Yosemite, Apple ships 2.7.6.  You can either upgrade the additional Python, for example, by downloading and installing the latest Python 2 from python.org (currently 2.7.9), or follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4/) to remove it.